# Solving $\ge 2$ congruences by CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

How do I get the solution given by CRT to match another solution, e.g. the least positive?

For example say I have `X = 1234`. I choose `mi` as `5, 7, 11, 13`. This satisfies the simple requirements of [Mignotte's threshold secret sharing scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing_using_the_Chinese_remainder_theorem#Mignotte.27s_threshold_secret_sharing_scheme). More precisely given in my example `k = n = 4`, and the product of any `k - 1` is smaller then `X` how come simply computing the remainder of each won't give equations that solve to `X = 1234`.

In the case of the example,

```
x = 4 mod 5
x = 2 mod 7
x = 2 mod 11
x = 12 mod 13
```

Which resolves to [31264](https://www.mathcelebrity.com/chinese.php?matrix1=x+%3D+4+mod+5%0D%0Ax+%3D+2+mod+7%0D%0Ax+%3D+2+mod+11%0D%0Ax+%3D+12+mod+13&pl=Solve+using+Chinese+Remainder+Theorem) (won't CRT produce the smallest?)

Any hints?

---

Below is the solution linked to on "Math Celebrity" (cached to avoid link rot).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The final result of the CRT calculation must be reduced modulo 5 x 7 x 11 x 13 = 5005. This gives the correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

As proved in General Easy CRT below, solutions of such congruence systems are necessarily unique $\!\bmod M = $ lcm of all moduli. But a CRT algorithm (or formula) need not always return the *least nonnegative* solution, so we must reduce it $\!\bmod M\,$ if we seek such a normalized solution. Doing so in the OP we get $\,31264\bmod 5005  \equiv 1234,\,$ where $\,M = 5005 = {\rm lcm}(5,7,11,13)$.

Below is a much simpler way to immediately obtain the answer. Contrast the solution below to the much longer solution in your link, which involves calculations with much larger numbers, and performs $4$ inversions vs. the single simple inversion below. **Tip:** search for hidden innate structure in a problem before diving head-first into brute-force mechanical calculations.

Below we use *modular fractions* $\,a/b := ab^{-1}\pmod{\! n}.\,$ They are well defined when $\,b\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod n,\,$ i.e. when $\,b\,$ is coprime to $\,n.\,$ Generally common fraction arithmetic is valid $\!\bmod n\,$ provided we restrict to such fractions with denominator *coprime* to $\,n\,$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242)).

**Key Idea** $ $ the congruences split into pairs with obvious *constant* solutions [by CCRT,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) viz.

$$\begin{align}&\rm x\equiv \ \ \ 2\ \ (mod\,\ 7),\ \ x\equiv \ \ \ 2\ \ \:(mod\ \,11) \iff\ x\equiv \ \ \ \color{#0a0}2\ \ (mod\,\ \color{#0a0}{77})\\[0.3em]
&\rm x\equiv -1\ \ (mod\,\ 5),\,\  x\equiv\ {-}1\ \ (mod\,\ 13) \iff\ x\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\ \ (mod\,\ \color{#c00}{65})\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Thus the above $4$ original LHS equations are *equivalent* to the above $2$ RHS equations. The latter $2$ are easy to solve by CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem.  $ $ Indeed, applying **Easy CRT** below

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad x\equiv\ \color{#0a0}{2 + 77}\ \bigg[\displaystyle\frac{\color{#c00}{-1}-\color{#0a0}2}{\color{#0a0}{77}}\ mod\,\, \color{#c00}{65}\bigg]\,\ \ (mod\ 77\cdot65),\ $ so computing the fraction

by [twiddling](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) $\: \rm\displaystyle\left[\, mod\ \ 65\!:\ \ \frac{\color{#c00}{-1}-\color{#0a0}2}{\color{#0a0}{77}} \equiv \frac{-3}{12} \equiv \frac{-1}4 \equiv \frac{64}4 \equiv \color{#d0f}{16}\,\right]\ \  $   (see **Beware** below)

thus we get $\rm\ \ x\, \equiv\, \color{#0a0}{2 + 77}\,[\,\color{#d0f}{16}\,] \equiv 1234\ \ (mod\ 77\cdot 65)$. $\ \ \bf\small QED$

---

**Or** $\: x\!-\!\color{#0a0}2\bmod \color{#0a0}{77}(65) = \color{#0a0}{77}\left[\dfrac{\color{#c00}x\!-\!2}{77}\bmod 65\right] =  77\left[\dfrac{\color{#c00}{-1}\!-\!2}{77}\bmod \color{#c00}{65}\right]\! = 77(\color{#d0f}{16}) $ as above, by employing $\:\color{#0a0}ab\bmod \color{#0a0}ac = \:\color{#0a0}a\:[\,b\bmod c]\,$ [(mod Distributive Law)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242) to factor $\,\color{#0a0}{a \!=\! 77}\,$ out of a $\!\bmod\!.$

As above, the Easy CRT formula is viewable as a special case of the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), which yields an *operational* form of CRT that proves very convenient for calculation.

---

**Theorem** $ $  **(Easy CRT)** $\  $ If $\ m,n\,$ are coprime integers [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) $\ m^{-1}\ $ exists $\!\pmod{\! n}\, $ and

$$\begin{eqnarray} x&\equiv&\!\ a\!\!\pmod{\!m} \\
 x&\equiv&\!\ b\!\!\pmod{\!n}\end{eqnarray}\! \iff  x \equiv\, a + m\ \bigg[\frac{b-a}{m}\bmod n\,\bigg]\!\!\!\pmod{\!mn}\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ (\Leftarrow)\ \ \bmod m\!:\,\ x \equiv a + m\ [\,\cdots\,] \equiv a,\ $ and $\bmod n\!:\,\ x \equiv a + (b\!-\!a)\ m/m \equiv b$

$ (\Rightarrow)\ \ $ Solutions are unique $\bmod mn\ $ since if $\ x',\,x\ $ are solutions then $\ x'\equiv x\ $ mod $\,m\ \&\ n\,$ therefore $\ m,n\ |\ x'-x\ \Rightarrow\ mn\ |\ x'-x\ \ $ [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/696242/242) $\ \,m,n\,$ coprime $\,\Rightarrow\ {\rm lcm}(m,n) = mn$. $\ \ \bf\small QED$

**Note** $ $ Easy CRT is not only easy to apply, but also very easy to *remember / derive*. Note that $\ x\equiv a\pmod{\! m}\!\iff\! x = a + m\,k,\,$ for some integer $\,k.\,$ This satisfies the second congruence $ $ $\!\iff$ $\!\!\bmod n\!:\ x = a + m\,k\equiv b\!$ $\iff$ $\! k\,\equiv (b-a)/m,\, $ yielding the Easy CRT formula. This explains the $(\Leftarrow)$ proof: $ $ fill in the dots in: $\,x\equiv \color{#0a0}a + \color{#c00}m\ [\,\cdots\,]\,$ to make it $\equiv  \color{#90f}b\pmod{\! n},\,$ viz. the $\,m\,$ in the denominator cancels $\,\color{#c00}m,\,$ and then the $\,\color{90f}b\color{0a0}{-a}\,$ in the numerator cancels $\,\color{#0a0}a\,$ then adds the sought $\,\color{#90f}b\,$ to obtain $\, x\equiv b\pmod{\!n},\,$ exactly what was done in the above algebra solving for $\, x.$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2368266/242) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3434593/242) for  methods to compute modular inverses (or fractions) in the above CRT formula.

---

The Theorem  generalizes to *noncoprime* moduli  by cancelling $\,\color{darkorange}{d=\gcd(m,n)\,\ \rm everywhere}$.

**General Easy CRT** $ $ The congruence system below is solvable $\!\iff\!   \color{#c00}{\color{darkorange}d:=\gcd(m,n)\mid a-b}.\,$ When solvable the solution is $\,\color{#0a0}{{\rm unique}\ \bmod mn/\color{darkorange}d} = {\rm lcm}(m,n)\,$ as given below.

$$\begin{align} &x\equiv\!\ a\!\!\pmod{\! m}\\
 &x\equiv\:\! b\!\!\pmod{\! n}\end{align}\!\iff  x \equiv\, a + m\ \bigg[\frac{(b-a)/\color{darkorange}d}{m/\color{darkorange}d}\bmod{n/\color{darkorange}d}\,\bigg]\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{mn/\color{darkorange}d}}\qquad$$

**Proof** $\, $ The solvability $\rm\color{#c00}{criterion}$ is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242). For $\rm\color{#0a0}{uniqueness}$, if $\,x,\bar x\,$ are both solutions then $\,x\equiv a\equiv \bar x\pmod{\!m}\,$ so $\,m\mid x-\bar x.\,$ Similarly $\,n\mid x-\bar x,\,$ so $\,{\rm lcm}(m,n) = \color{#0a0}{mn/\color{darkorange}d}\mid x-\bar x,\,$ as in [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242). The solution formula can be obtained by specializing that in the first theorem using [modular fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) by cancelling $\,\color{darkorange}{d\,\ \rm everywhere}$ in the bracketed fraction, or derived directly, viz. $\,x\equiv a\pmod{\!m}\!\iff\! x = a + km\,$ for some $\,k\in\Bbb Z,\,$ which will satisfy the 2nd congruence
$$\begin{align}
\iff \bmod n\!:\quad\  b\,\equiv\, x\,&\equiv\,\ a+k\,m\\[.2em] 
     \iff\quad\ \  k\,m\,&\equiv\ \, b-a,\,\ \text{so cancelling }\, \color{darkorange}{d\,\ \rm everywhere}\\[.2em] 
\iff \bmod n/\color{darkorange}d\!:\,\  k\,m/\color{darkorange}d\, &\equiv\, (b-a)/\color{darkorange}d,\,\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \color{#c00}{\color{darkorange}d\mid a-b}\\[.3em]
     \iff\qquad\ \ \ k &\equiv \frac{(b-a)/\color{darkorange}d}{m/\color{darkorange}d},\ \ {\rm by}\,\ (m/d,n/d)=1.\ \ \ \bf\small QED\end{align}\qquad$$

---

**Efficiently solving $\,n > 2\,$ congruences a pair at a time using the above method**

The solvability criterion [extends](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1181523/242) to any number of congruences, i.e. the system is solvable iff each pair is solvable - as above. Thus when the system is solvable we can use the above method to replace any *pair* of congruences by an equivalent *single* congruence, so iterating we eventually reach a *single* congruence which is equivalent to the system. This is often the easiest general way to solve such congruence systems (its uses only *efficient* gcd operations vs. *inefficient* prime factorization used in [alternative methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/120144/242)). For a worked example see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1209732/242).

**Beware** $ $ modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. Then $\,a/b := ab^{-1}\,$ uniquely exists and fraction arithmetic works as usual for such  modular fractions. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

---

**CRT solution via [fractional extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)**

$\begin{align} x&\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod{\!8}\\ x&\equiv 7\!\!\!\pmod{\!125}\end{align}$
$\iff \begin{align} 125x&\equiv 125\!\!\!\pmod{\!1000}\\ 8x&\equiv 56\pmod{\!1000}\end{align}$

${\rm mod}\ 1000\!:\,\ x\equiv \dfrac{125}{125} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{56}{\color{#90f}{8}} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{229}}{\color{#0a0}{-3}} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{-257}{-1}$

$\!\begin{array}{rrl}  \text{or, equationally:}\ \ \ [\![1]\!]\!\!\!& 125\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \ 125\\ 
[\![2]\!]\!\!\!&\ \color{#90f}{8}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \ \ \ 56\\ [\![1]\!]-16[\![2]\!]\equiv:[\![3]\!]\!\!\!&\ \color{#0a0}{{-}3}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\,\ \  \color{#c00}{229}\\ 
[\![2]\!]\ +\ 3[\![3]\!]\equiv:[\![4]\!]\!\!\!&\ {-}x\!\!\! &\equiv  {-}257\\ \end{array}$

---

Below is a simple example with *noncoprime* moduli (from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/735737/242))

$\begin{align} x&\equiv 6\!\!\!\pmod{\!10}\\ x&\equiv 8\!\!\!\pmod{\!12}\end{align}\!$
$\underset{\times 5}{\overset{\times 6}\iff} \begin{align} 6x&\equiv 36\!\!\!\pmod{\!60}\\ 5x&\equiv 40\!\!\!\pmod{\!60}\end{align}$

${\rm mod}\,\ 60\!:\,\ x\equiv \dfrac{36}{6} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{40}{\color{#90f}{5}} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{\color{#c00}{-4}}{\color{#0a0}{1}} $

$\!\begin{array}{rrl}  \text{equationally:} \ \ [\![1]\!]\!\!\!&\  6\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\  36\\ 
[\![2]\!]\!\!\!&\ \color{#90f}{5}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv \ 40\\ 
[\![1]\!]-[\![2]\!]\equiv:[\![3]\!]\!\!\!&\ \color{#0a0}{1}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv \color{#c00}{-4} \end{array}$

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: But the OP was just giving an example! Your solution is completely useless for any other, similar problem. Unless you can automate it, of course :-)

Comment: @TonyK: Most certainly not true. Most math problems do have interesting structure, esp. problems that are designed for tests, competitions etc. In fact this is frequently true even in research problems. Indeed, speaking as a number theorist, I can tell you that methods like the above are very useful in practice. **In mathematics, intuition always trumps brute force**.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Well, your methods might be much, much simpler for you. But if they require years of practice, they're not so useful for people like me (or, presumably, the OP).

Comment: @Tonyk: The above solution can be understood by a bright high-school student. Simple optimizations like the above arise frequently in elementary number theoretical problems, so it is well-worth knowing them.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Yes, I can follow your solution easily enough. But I wouldn't trust myself to be able to generate such a solution on arbitrary input. You yourself mentioned a "key insight". My point is, any method that requires a key insight is not useful. Not an algorithm, if you will.

Comment: @TonyK: The optimization I employed above *is* algorithmic and is frequently applicable in practice. But that was not my point in presenting the above. Rather, it was to emphasize conceptual vs. algorithmic thought - intuition vs. brute force. Mathematical problems are far from random. Typically they involve much structure and their solution requires insightful exploitation of such innate structure - something that cannot be algorithmic (indeed many math problems are algorithmically unsolvable - that's what makes them interesting).

Comment: @BillDubuque Could you elaborate on the right arrow direction of the Easy CRT proof?

Comment: @Code Where are you stuck?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus You might find helpful [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860148/242) on CCRT = Constant-case CRT.

Comment: @TonyK FYI:  there are now [$59$ posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/190514?lq=1) linked to CCRT = Constant-case CRT, so it surely is frequently *useful* (likely there are many hundreds of possible applications here but many authors don't invoke it by name).

Comment: @BillDubuque: I about the Easy CRT. I don't really understand it. So I do understand that since $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $m$ has a multiplicative inverse. But I dont really understand how we switch from modulo $m$ to $n$ in the formulas

Comment: @Jim What do you mean by "switch from modulo ..."?

Comment: @BillDubuque: It was something I was confused about because I hadn't review the topic for a long time but I cleared it out. Thank you for checking back