# Where is the mistake in this reasoning?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If we make a table such that each column contains numbers modulo $m$ and each row containing numbers modulo $n$. Let us denote the element $a_{ij}=x$ and $a_{i'j'}=y$ Where $0\leq i,i'<m$ and $0\leq j,j'<n$. 
$$x\equiv i \quad(mod \;m)$$ 
$$x\equiv j \quad(mod \;n)$$ 
$$y\equiv i' \quad(mod \;m)$$ 
$$y\equiv j' \quad(mod \;n)$$

This is essentially how I translate a program i wrote to generate those tables and it works fine. (loop over every number, then decide its indices). I am now trying to show that no two numbers in the table are same (which is so if $m,n$ are coprime)

Start by supposing that $x=y$ then,
$$i\equiv i' \quad(mod \;m)$$ 
 $$j\equiv j' \quad(mod \;n)$$

But because  $0\leq i,i'<m$ and $0\leq j,j'<n$, we have $i=i'$ and $j=j'$. Hence no two numbers in this table are the same.

However, there has to be a mistake here as I never took into account $m$ and $n$ to be coprime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem when $m$ and $n$ are not coprime is that some positions in the table cannot be filled; for instance, if $m=6$ and $n=10$, $a_{01}$ is undefined. Your argument correctly shows that the entries that *can* be defined must all be distinct.

Comment: But the problem is, for $m=6$ and $n=10$  we have $\;a_{00}=0\mbox{ and }30$. So for an entry, the above "proof" of mine can also be reversed to show that if $i=i'$ and $j=j'$ then $x=y$, which is clearly not true as we can have two different numbers in a position.

Comment: @kuch nani: You are confusing the issue of whether, *given one specific way of filling in the table*, two entries can be the same, vs. *whether there is more than one way of filling in the table*. It is true that there is more than one way of filling in the table; but Brian's point is that, given two entries in different locations, they cannot be equal.

Comment: @Kuch: Why do you think that it reverses? $x=y$ implies that $i\equiv i'\pmod m$ and $j\equiv j'\pmod n$, but the reverse implication is false.

Answer (score 1):

It is an immediate consequence of *uniqueness* of solutions in CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem). The proof is easy.  If $\,\gcd(m,n) = 1\,$ then  $\ x\bmod  mn\ \to\ (x\bmod m,\ x\bmod n)\ $ is $\,1$ to $1.\ $ For if $\ x,\,y\ $ map to the same value then $\, x\equiv y\pmod{\!m}\, $ so $\ m\ |\ x-y\,,\,$ i.e. $\,m\,$ divides $\,x-y\,.\,$ Similarly $\,n\ |\ x-y\,.\,$ Hence $\, {\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid x-y\,.\,$ But $\,\gcd(m,n) = 1 \!\iff\! {\rm lcm}(m,n) = mn.\,$ Thus $\ mn = {\rm lcm}(m,n)\ |\ x-y\,,\,$ hence $\, x \equiv y\pmod{\!mn}\,.\,$ Hence indeed the map is $1$ to $1$.

Conversely, if $\,{\rm lcm}(m,n) < mn\ $ then $\,x\,$ and $\ x + {\rm lcm}(m,n)\ $ are not congruent $\!\bmod\ mn.\,$ However, both map to the same value $\ (x\bmod m,\, x\bmod n),\,$ since both $\,m,n\mid {\rm lcm}(m,n)\,.\ $ This explains the example you gave in your comment, where $\,m,n = 6,10\,$ so $\,{\rm lcm}(m,n) = 30,\,$ hence $\, x= 0\,$ and $\,x+30 = 30\,$ both map to $\,(0,0)\,$ but $\, 30\not\equiv 0\pmod{\!60}$.

The *existence* of solutions is also easy. Clearly $\ |\mathbb Z\bmod mn| = mn = |\mathbb Z\bmod m \times \mathbb Z\bmod n|,\, $ thus the above map being $1$ to $1$ on these equal cardinality finite sets implies the map is  also *onto*, i.e. every pair $\,(i\bmod\ m,\,j\bmod n)\,$ is the image of some $\, x\bmod\ mn.\,$

In summary: if $\,\gcd(m,n) = 1$ then the congruence system $\ x\equiv i\pmod{\!m},\ x\equiv j\ \pmod{\!n}\, $ has a unique solution $\!\bmod\ mn,\,$ i.e. if $\,x',x\,$ are solutions then $\,x'\equiv x\pmod{\!mn}.\,$ For a simple *constructive* proof [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20223/getting-an-x-for-chinese-remainder-theorem-crt/20259#20259)