# A "fast" approach to solve $2^{133} \equiv x \mod 133 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have to solve this equation $2^{133} \equiv x \mod  133 $.Using Euler's theorem I reduced it to $2^{25} \equiv x \mod 133$ but I couldn't think off any fast way to proceed after this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do it mod 7 and mod 19, then use Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: $2^{25}=2(2^{3\cdot 8})=2((8^2)^2)^2$.  If you compute by doing repeated squaring and reduce mod 133 every time you square, the numbers you work with won't be too big.

Comment: And even the original $2^{133}$ is $2^{2^7}\times 2^5$, which can be done in less than ten modular multiplications.

Comment: @Foolmath: I don't understand your point. Do $x \equiv a$ and $a \equiv x$ feel different to you?

Comment: @Soarer:I get your point,but using CRT isn't really fast approach for this problem I guess.

Comment: @FoolForMath: What do you mean by fast? This is actually quite fast in my opinion. If you mean fast in the context of using computers, then Henning's method above should suffice.

Comment: @Soarer:Fast means solving the whole problem under a minute manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT** $\ $  for primes $\rm\: p\ne q,\ \ p\!-\!1\ |\ q\!-\!1\  \Rightarrow\ c^{q}\equiv\: c\pmod{p\:q}\ $ by Fermat's little Theorem.

So for $\rm\:p,q = 7,19,\ c = 2^7\:$ we infer that $\rm\: 2^{\:7\:\cdot\: 19}\equiv 2^7\equiv 128 \equiv {-}5 \pmod{7\cdot 19}\ \ $ **QED**

**Proof** $\ $ Assume $\rm\ p \ne q\ $ are primes and  $\rm\: q = 1 + k\:(p-1)\:,\ k\in \mathbb N\:.\: $  By Fermat's little Theorem $\rm\:mod\ q\!:\ c^q = c\:;\ \ \ mod\ p\!:\ c^q =\: c^{\:1+k\:(p-1)} =\: c\ (c^{\:p-1})^{k}\equiv\: c\ $ if $\rm\:c\not\equiv\: 0\:,\:$ and $\rm\:c^q\equiv c\:$ if $\rm\:c\equiv 0\:.\:$
Therefore  $\rm\:p,q\ |\ c^q-c\:$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:lcm(p,q) =\: p\:q\ |\ c^q-c\:.\ \ $ **QED**

**NOTE** $\ $ The above proposition is a special case of a general [Fermat-Euler-Carmichael Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/modular-exponentiation-using-eulers-theorem/1726#1726)

Note that this is yet another example of [constant case optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64157/modular-arithmetic-question-possibly-involving-chinese-remainder-theorem/64228#64228) of Chinese Remainder (CRT).

Comment: what is odd primes?I didn't understand your approach at all :/

Comment: @FoolForMath: Odd primes means primes that are odd, i.e., bigger than 2.  For the first implication: To see that $p | 2^{pq} - 2^p$, apply Fermat's Little Theorem (FLT) for $p$ twice, using the condition $p-1 | q-1$.  To see that $q | 2^{pq} - 2^p$, apply FLT for $q$.

Comment: @Foo I've appended a *complete* proof below the hint.

Answer (score 2):

Use $133 = 7 \times 19$. Use $2^p = 2 \mod p$ for $p \in \mathbb{P}$.

Now $2^{133} = (2^7)^{19} \mod 7 = 2^{19} \mod 7 = (2^7)^2 \times 2^5 = 2^2 \times 2^5 = 2^7 = 2 \mod 7$. Similarly $2^{133} = (2^{19})^7 = 2^7 = 14 \mod 19$. Thus

Let $x = 2^{133} \mod 133$, then from $x = 14 \mod 19$, it follows that  $x = 14 + 19 \times k$. From $x = 2 \mod 7$, it follows $(14 + 19 \times k) = 5 \times k = 2 \mod 7$, and $k = 6 \mod 7$. From this I get $2^{133} = 128 \mod 133$.

Comment: +1,I understood this approach,for the last part I used CRT,however not much a fast way I guess.