# Chinese Remainder Theorem Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am really stuck on this problem.

Solve the following system of simultaneous congruences

$X + 3Y \equiv 2 \pmod5 \hspace{50pt} X+2Y \equiv 3 \pmod5$

$ X + 2Y \equiv 3 \pmod7 \hspace{50pt} 2X + Y \equiv 4 \pmod7$

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem I have found separate solutions to

$ 1) \hspace{5pt} x \equiv 2 \pmod 5   \hspace{30pt} and \hspace{30pt} 2) \hspace{5pt} x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$

$ \hspace{12pt}x \equiv 3 \pmod 7  \hspace{30pt}  \hspace{58pt} x \equiv 4 \pmod 7$

These are $x =17$ for $ \ 1) \ $ and $ \ x = 18$ for $ \ 2)$. Is this even the right way to proceed, and if it is where do you go from here?

Any help would be really good!

Comment: I see four equations in $x,y$... Do they correspond to two different sets of equations?

Comment: No I don't think they do. I am pretty sure you have to find a $X$ and $Y$ that satisfies all four at once.

Comment: I wonder, is there a matrix version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem? Ah, here is one [paper](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/preprints/linear.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ It's a simple *constant case* of CRT: $\:\!$  if $\rm\:gcd(m,n)=1\:$ then $\rm\:lcm(m,n) = mn,\:$ hence

$\rm\qquad\ \ \ x \equiv a\pmod{m,n}\iff m,n\ |\ x-a\iff mn\ |\ x-a\iff x\equiv a\pmod{mn}$

Thus $\rm\:\!\ \ X+2Y \equiv 3\ \:(mod\ 5,7)\iff X+2Y \equiv 3\pmod{35}\qquad\quad\ \ \ [1]$

and $\rm\ \ \ \: 2X+Y \equiv 4\ \:(mod\ 5,7)\iff 2X+Y \equiv 4\pmod{35}\qquad\quad\ \ \ [2]$

Now $\rm\ 2\cdot [1] - [2]\ \Rightarrow\: 3Y\equiv 2 \equiv -33\ \Rightarrow\  Y \equiv -11\ \Rightarrow\ X \equiv 3-2Y \equiv 25$

**Remark** $\ $ This simple constant-case optimization of CRT arises quite frequently in practice, esp. for small moduli (by the law of small numbers), so it is well worth checking for. For further examples, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) where it simplified a few page calculation to a few lines, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/64228/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73541/242)

Comment: Thank you very much that makes alot of sense! Also thanks for all the useful links.

Answer (score 1):

First solve the two congruences modulo 5 to get values of $x$ modulo 5 and $y$ modulo 5. Then do the same for the two congruences modulo 7. Then use Chinese Remainder Theorem to get values of $x$ and $y$ modulo 35.