# $x \equiv a \pmod{p}$ and $x \equiv a \pmod{q}\iff x \equiv a\pmod{pq},\ $ i.e. CCRT = Constant case CRT [Chinese Remainder Theorem]

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Prove $x \equiv a \pmod{p}$ and $x \equiv a \pmod{q}$ then $x \equiv a\pmod{pq}$ for $p\neq q$ distinct primes.

Where can I start with this proof?
It looks similar to the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but that deals with two different a values.

Comment: *but that deals with two different $a$ values* - What makes you think that?

Comment: Because for the explanations of Chinese Remainder Theorem I've read, they use something like a = x (mod p) and a = y (mod p)

Comment: A couple of variables denoted with two different letters may take on two different values, *but not necessarily unless they are explicitly stated to have distinct values.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few  proofs of the ubiquitous $\small \bf CCRT = \bf{Constant\!\!-\!\!case \ CRT}\,$  [Chinese Remainder Theorem].

**Theorem (CCRT)** $\rm\ \ \  \begin{align}&\rm x\equiv a\!\!\pmod{\!p}\\  &\rm x\equiv a\!\!\pmod{\!q}\end{align}\!\iff x\equiv a\pmod{\!pq}\,$ if $\rm\,p,q\,$ are coprime,

$\rm\qquad said\ equivalently\!:\quad p,q\mid x-a\iff pq\mid x-a,\ $ if $\ \rm p,q\,$ are coprime

$\rm\qquad said\ equivalently\!:\qquad\ \ \  lcm(p,q)\, =\, pq,\ \ if\ \ p,q\,$ are coprime

**Proof** $\ $ For variety we give a few different proofs.

$\rm(1)\ \ \ x \equiv a\pmod {\!pq}\:$ is clearly a solution, and the solution is $\color{#C00}{unique}$ mod $\rm\,pq\,$ by CRT. $ $ [Note: rotely applying the common CRT formula [also yields](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4074559/242) this obvious solution].

$\rm(2)\ \ \ p,q\:|\:x\!-\!a\iff lcm(p,q)\:|\:x\!-\!a\:$ by the [Universal Property of $\rm lcm$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242).
$\qquad\! $ Further $\rm\:(p,q)=1^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\!\iff lcm(p,q) = pq,\,$ by [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1136611/242)

$(3)\ \, $ By [Euclid's Lemma:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690282/242) $\rm\:(p,q)=1,\ p\:|\:qn =\:x\!-\!a\:\Rightarrow\:p\:|\:n\:\Rightarrow\:pq\:|\:nq = x\!-\!a.$

$\rm(4)\ \, $  The list of prime factors of $\rm\,p\,$ occurs in one factorization of $\,\rm x-a\,$, and the disjoint list of prime factors of $\rm\,q\,$ occurs in another. By $\color{#C00}{uniqueness}$, the prime factorizations are the same up to order, so the concatenation of these disjoint lists of primes occurs in $\rm\,x-a,\,$ hence  $\rm\,pq\mid x-a$.

$\rm(5)\ \, $ Applying the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2059752/242), a handy *operational* form of CRT

$$\rm p\mid x\!-\!a\,\Rightarrow\, x\!-\!a\bmod pq = p\left[\dfrac{\color{#c00}{x\!-\!a}}p\bmod q\right] = p[\color{#c00}0]=0\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{x\equiv a}\!\!\!\pmod{\!q}\qquad$$

**Remark** $\ $ This *constant-case optimization* of CRT arises frequently in practice so is well-worth memorizing, e.g. see [some prior posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+constant+case+crt) for many examples.

[Quite frequently](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amath.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+powerful++tools+equalities)  $\color{#C00}{uniqueness}$ *theorems* provide powerful tools for **proving equalities.**

[More generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281011/242) this idea works for values & moduli in A.P.  $\ $  if $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ then

**APCRT** $\ \ \left\{\,x\equiv d\!-\!ck\!\pmod{b\!-\!ak}\,\right\}_{k=0}^{n}\!\!\iff\! x\equiv \dfrac{ad\!-\!bc}a\!\!\!\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{b\!-\!ak\}_{k=0}^n}$
$ $ e.g.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3395019/242) $\  \underbrace{\left\{\,x \equiv 3-k\pmod{7-k}\,\right\}_{k=0}^2}_{\!\!\!\!\!\!\textstyle{x\equiv 3,2,1\pmod{\!7,6,5}}}\!\iff  x\equiv \dfrac{1(3)\!-\!7(1)^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}}1\equiv -4\pmod{\!210}$

Comment: in (2) do you mean to say $gcd(p, q) = 1 \iff lcm(p, q) = pq$

Comment: @Code Yes, $\rm\:(x,y)\:$ means $\rm\:gcd(x,y)\:$ in number theory (common notation).

Answer (score 5):

Let $[A,B]=\operatorname{lcm}(A,B)$ and $(A,B)=\gcd(A,B)$

If $p,q$ are different integers,  $p\mid(x-a)$  and $q\mid(x-a)\implies [p,q]\mid(x-a)$

We know $[p,q]\cdot (p,q)=p\cdot q$

If $(p,q)=1, [p,q]=p\cdot q$

If $p,q$ are distinct primes, $(p,q)=1$

Answer (score 4):

Let $y=x-a$. We want to show that if $p$ divides $y$ and $q$ divides $y$ then $pq$ divides $y$.

Since $p$ divides $y$, we have $y=pz$ for some $z$.  Thus $q$ divides $pz$. Since $q$ is prime, this implies $q$ divides $p$ or $q$ divides $z$. But $q$ cannot divide $p$, so $q$ divides $z$. Suppose that $z=qw$. Then $y=pqw$.