# A part of modular arithmetic I jut dont get, badly stuck for an answer. Help please?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

A housewife is travelling to market with all her eggs in one basket. She has between 100 and 200 eggs in the basket. Counting in threes there are 2 eggs leftover, counting in fives there are 2 eggs leftover and counting in sevens there are 3 eggs leftover. How many eggs are in the basket?

Comment: This has only to do with modular arithmetic, please remove the other three tags.

Answer (score 2):

Could you write this up?
$$\begin{align} x&\equiv 2 \pmod{3} \\
 x &\equiv 2 \pmod{5} \\
 x & \equiv 3 \pmod{7}
\end{align}$$

These are small numbers, you can also find manually a *common remainder* of these three. 
In general, if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then

> $$\big( x\equiv a\pmod{m}\ \text{ and }\ x\equiv a\pmod{n} \big) \iff 
> x\equiv a \pmod{mn}$$

Well, two of the remainders above are already common, so we can write one instead of them:
$$\begin{align} x&\equiv 2 \pmod{15} \\
 x & \equiv 3 \pmod{7}
\end{align}$$

Now. Can you find a common remainder of them?

Well, for example $2\equiv 17 \pmod{15}$ and $17\equiv 10 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, so $x\equiv 17$ is good:
$$x\equiv 17 \pmod{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}$$
How many solutions does it give between $100$ and $200$?

Comment: The first step uses the [constant-case optimization of CRT,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) which often proves handy in practice. You can find many examples in my [prior posts.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+constant+case+crt) The second step is best generally done with [Easy CRT.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) $\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

$x=2+3k$. Therefore $2+3k \equiv 2  \ \ (5)$. This gives $k=5t$. So, $x=2+15t$.  Finally
$2+15 t \equiv 3 \ \ (7)$ which means that $t=1+7s$. So, $x=17 +105 s$. For $s=1$ we get $x=122$.

Comment: Note that $\:122 \equiv 17\pmod{\!105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ 5,7\:|\:2x\!+\!1\:\Rightarrow\:35\:|\:2x\!+\!1\:\Rightarrow\:mod\ 35\!:\ x\equiv \dfrac{-1}2\equiv \dfrac{34}2\equiv 17.\:$ Also $17\equiv 2\pmod 3.\:$

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  Working with the congruences $x \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ and $x \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$, we compute the multiplicative inverse of 3 modulo 5 as 2, and of 5 modulo 3 as 2; hence $x \equiv 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \pmod {15}$.  Repeating for the congruences $x \equiv 2 \pmod{15}$ and $x \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, we get the multiplicative inverse of 7 modulo 15 is 13 and of 15 modulo 7 is 1; hence $x \equiv 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 13 + 3 \cdot 15 \cdot 1 \equiv 17 \pmod{105}$.  122 is the only integer between 100 and 200 with remainder 17 modulo 105.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the number of eggs in the basket. By hypothesis, both $3$ and $5$ are factors of $n-2$, so $15$ is a factor of $n-2$, and so $n=15j+2$ for some integer $j$. Since $100\le n\le 200$ and $j$ is an integer, then $7\le j\le 13$. At this point, you want to see which of these $j$ will give $n=15j+2$ the form $n=7m+3$ for some integer $m$. In other words, you want to find for which of these $j$ that $7$ is a factor of $n-3=15j-1$. Well, $n-3=14j+j-1$, and $7$ is always a factor of $14j$, so we really only need to choose our $j$ so that $7$ is a factor of $j-1$. The only possibility is $j=8$, whence $n=15j+2=122$.