# Solve congruence system $\ x\equiv m_i-1 \pmod{m_i}\,$ for $\,i = 1,\ldots, k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Find natural number $x$ so that
$$\begin{align}x&\equiv 9\pmod{10}\\ x&\equiv8\pmod9\\ &\ \ \vdots\\ x&\equiv 1\pmod2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The unnatural number $-1$ works.

Comment: I ask for natural number not integer

Comment: @user119081: Yes, you did. But André's hint is still a good one. How could you find a second integer solution from that one? Could you make the second solution natural?

Comment: Yes, I know. But from my solution $-1$, which is not a natural number, one can find a natural number solution, indeed all natural number solutions.  I am leaving the discovery of that, at least for a while, to you.

Comment: I believe this should be exist a natural solution by extended Euclidean algorithm

Comment: You could use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but only after dealing with the fact not all your moduli are relatively prime. But that is very much the hard way for these very special numbers.

Comment: While waiting, perhaps you can think of this. What number(s) can you **add** to my solution to get a natural number solution?

Comment: In fact, I saw this in the a school problem book as a hard question. But I could not respond to this question

Comment: Let $b$ be the least common multiple of the numbers $2$ to $10$. The positive integer solutions are $-1+bk$, where $k$ ranges over the positive integers. So the smallest positive solution is $2520-1$. An easier positive solution is $10!-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since  $\,m_i-1\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\pmod{\!m_i}\,$ we can apply $ $ [CCRT = $\rm\color{#c00}{constant}$ case optimization of CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)

$$\begin{align} x\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\!\!\pmod{\!m_i}&\iff x\equiv -1\!\!\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{m_i\}}\\[.4em]
\text{or, without using $\rm{\small CRT\!:}$}\ \ \ {\rm  all}\ \  m_i \mid x+1 &\iff {\rm lcm}\{m_i\}\mid x+1
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$
The latter equivalence is by the [Universal Property of LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) (= *definition* of LCM  in general)

**Remark** $ $ [more generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281011/242) this idea works for linearly related values & moduli:  $ $  if $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ then

$$\left\{\,x\equiv d\!-\!ck\!\!\!\pmod{b\!-\!ak}\,\right\}_{k=0}^{n}\!\!\iff\! x\equiv \dfrac{ad\!-\!bc}a\!\!\!\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{b\!-\!ak\}_{k=0}^n}\quad  \   $$

$ $ e.g.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3395019/242) $\,\ \underbrace{\left\{\,x \equiv 3-k\pmod{7-k}\,\right\}_{k=0}^2}_{\textstyle{x\equiv 3,2,1\pmod{\!7,6,5}}}\!\!\iff\!  x\equiv \dfrac{1(3)-7(1)}1\equiv -4\pmod{210}$

Comment: It suffices to find any common multiple $\,m\,$ of all the moduli $\,m_i$ (e.g. their product) and let $\,x = m+1,\,$ since then $\,x-1 = m\,$ is divisible by all $\,m_i,\,$ so, by above, is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   x &\equiv 9 \pmod{10} \\
   x &\equiv 8 \pmod 9 \\
   x &\equiv 7 \pmod 8 \\
   x &\equiv 6 \pmod 7 \\
   x &\equiv 5 \pmod 6 \\
   x &\equiv 4 \pmod 5 \\
   x &\equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\
   x &\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \\
   x &\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
\end{align}

Is equivalent to

\begin{align}
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod{10} \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 9 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 8 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 7 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 6 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 5 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 4 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 3 \\
   x &\equiv -1 \pmod 2 \\
\end{align}

which is equivalent to

$$x \equiv -1 \mod{\operatorname{lcm}\{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}}$$

$$x \equiv -1 \pmod{2520}$$

$$x \equiv 2519 \pmod{2520}$$