# Solve simultaneous system of congruence $x\equiv 2\pmod{910}$ and $x\equiv 93\pmod{1001}$

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Solve simultaneous system of congruence

$$\text{$x\equiv 2\pmod{910} \qquad$ and $\qquad x\equiv 93\pmod{1001}$}$$

I tried Chinese remainder theorem on this, but it did not work. Is there a good strategy for solving simultaneous system of congruences when their modulus consist of the same multiples?

Comment: $910=91\cdot10$ and $1001=91\cdot11$, so the relevant coprime moduli are $10,11$ and $91$, the last being the greatest common factor. Luckily the given congruences are compatible modulo the gcd as $93\equiv2\pmod{91}$. CRT does the rest.

Comment: Hint: $ $ It's trivial since $\  93-2 = 1001-910\ $ so $\ x\equiv 910 -2 = 1001-93,\ $ see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$910 = 2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 13$ and $1001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13$. Therefore, from the first statement we have:

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod 2, \ \ 2 \pmod 5, \ \ 2 \pmod 7, \ \
 2 \pmod {13}$$

and from the second statement we have:
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod {7}, \ \ 5 \pmod {11}, \ \
 2 \pmod {13}$$

so now you can use the Chinese remainder theorem on:

$$x \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$$
$$x \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$$
$$x \equiv 2 \pmod {13}$$

Comment: Much easier to exploit CCRT - see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The first congruence **means** $x=910y+2$ for some $y\in\Bbb Z$. The condition
on $y$ for both congruences to hold is therefore
$$910y+2\equiv93\pmod{1001},$$
equivalently
$$910y\equiv91\pmod{1001}.$$
As $910$, $91$ and $1001$ are all multiples of $91$, then this congruence is equivalent to
$$10y\equiv1\pmod{11}$$
whose solution is
$$y\equiv10\pmod{11}.$$
This **means** that $y=11t+10$ where $t\in\Bbb Z$. Then
$$x=910(11t+10)+2=10010t+9102.$$
So the solution of the original pair of congruences is
$$x\equiv9102\pmod{10010}.$$

This method solves any pair of congruences $x\equiv a\pmod m$ and
$x\equiv b\pmod n$ provided these have a common solution.

Comment: Yes, the general algorithm / formula works easily enough here, but in this case there is special structure that makes it *completely trivial* - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\!\begin{align}{\rm Notice}\quad\ \, \color{#c00}{1001}-\color{#0a0}{910} &\,=\, \color{#c00}{93} - \color{#0a0}2\\[.1em]
\Rightarrow\ \color{90f}{{-}908} \ =\ \color{#0a0}{2 - 910} &\,=\, \color{#c00}{93-1001}\end{align}\ $  so it's **trivial** by by [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)
$\Rightarrow \begin{align} 
-\color{90f}{908}\ \equiv\  \color{#0a0}2&\equiv x \!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{910}}^{\phantom{|^{|^{|^.}}}}\\[.1em]
-\color{90f}{908}\equiv \color{#c00}{93} &\equiv x\!\!\!\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{1001}}\end{align}\!\!\!\iff \color{90f}{-908}\equiv x\smash[t]{\pmod{\!\overbrace{{\rm lcm}(910,1001)}^{1001(10)}}} $

**Remark** $ $ Generally this CRT optimization [works for linearly related values and moduli.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3395019/242)

Comment: and $\bmod 10010\!:\ \color{#0a0}{{-}908}\equiv 10010-908\equiv 9102\ \ $