# Proving identities (mod $pq$) using Fermat's little theorem?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have come across this question, which reminded me of Fermats little theorem, i dont know if the Fermats theorem is actually in use in the following mathematical statements

an integer a is a coprime with p and a coprime with q (p and q are different prime numbers )then prove that

$$a^{(p-1)(q-1)} \equiv 1(\operatorname{mod} pq) $$

$$p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv 1(\operatorname{mod} pq)$$

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to express the totient function from prime decompositions? What is $\phi(pq)$?

Comment: i started googling that, and got some helpful results thank you !

Comment: Take a look at Euler's totient as Arthur said and then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem

Comment: @Arthur  would you have any idea how i can find some helpful links proving this statement                                                                                      **2^(()−1) ≡ (+1)/2 (mod n) (if n is odd)**

Answer (score 1):

These are really Chinese Remainder Theorem problems.  First look mod $p$, then mod $q$.  IF the expression is congruent to the same thing mod $p$ and $q$, then CRT says they're also congruent to that "same thing" mod $pq$.

For the second problem $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv p^{q-1} +0 \equiv 1 (\bmod{q})$ by Fermat's little theorem.  Likewise $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\bmod{p})$.  So by CRT $p^{q-1}+q^{p-1} \equiv 1 (\bmod{pq}).$

The first problem has the same flavor.

Comment: I like your approach with the CRT. ill definitely look into that, thanks a lot!

Comment: would you have any idea how i can find some helpful links proving this statement                                                                                               **2^(()−1) ≡ (+1)/2 (mod n) (if n is odd)**

Comment: Euler's theorem says $2^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \equiv n+1 (\bmod{n})$.  Since $n$ is odd, $2$ has an inverse modulo $n$, so multiply through by $2^{-1}$.  Wiki should have a decent page about Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ By lil Fermat, both satisfy $\,x\equiv 1\,$ mod $\,p\ \&\ q\,$ thus $\,x\equiv 1\pmod{pq}\ $ by [CCRT.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) Or, more elementarily, we can prove  it directly:  $\ p,q\mid x\!-1\!\,$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\, pq\mid x\!-\!1,\,$ by $\,p,q\,$ coprime, by Euclid's Lemma or unique factorization. In fact the *uniqueness* of the CRT solution is [equivalent to the universal property of lcm,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) i.e. $\ p,q\mid n\iff {\rm lcm}(p,q)\mid n$