# How to solve system of congruence with common divisor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve these (4) systems of congruences?

$$
\begin{cases}
x=3,5\pmod{8}\\
x=5,7\pmod{12}
\end{cases}
$$
I was thinking about using CRT but $\gcd\left(8,12\right)>1$.

What can I do?

**Clarification:**

This notation represents 4 different systems. One of them for example is

$$
\begin{cases}
x=3\pmod{8}\\
x=7\pmod{12}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: use mod 24, 24=lcm(8,12)

Comment: @InterstellarProbe:  Likely $x$ congruent to $3$ or to $5$ mod $8$, etc.  So there are four separate problems tersely expressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As chí trunch châo mentioned. If you work $\textrm{mod}\ 24$, you should see that being $3\ \textrm{mod}\  8$ gives $(3,11,19)\ \textrm{mod}\  24$ (excuse my notation) and $5\ \textrm{mod}\  8$ gives $(5,13,21)\ \textrm{mod}\  24$. Moreover, $5\ \textrm{mod}\  12$ gives $(5,17)\ \textrm{mod}\  24$ and $7\ \textrm{mod}\  12$ gives $(7,19)\ \textrm{mod}\  24$. Looking at these possibilities and its intersection, it is not hard to see that the only two possibilities remaining are $5\ \textrm{mod}\  24$ and $19\ \textrm{mod}\  24$ which are solutions to the combinations $(5,5)$ and $(3,7)$, respectively.

Comment: Would this method work also for coprimes?

Comment: In general, you use the least common multiple (LCM). If they are coprime, you can even conclude that there always is a solution (Chinese Remainder Theorem)

Comment: So, yes, it definitely works for coprimes

Comment: Seems to be much faster looking for solutions this way than using CRT

Comment: Actually, the method uses the CRT

Comment: @Jon We can simplify matters by notiing the residues are all $\pm 5,$ see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As observed, the result, if any, will be expressed to modulus of the lowest common multiple of the two given modulus values - here, $\text{lcm}(8,12)=24$.

For a given combination we can examine the stated equivalence in the modulus of the $\gcd$ to assess if it is feasible. Here $\gcd(8,12)=4$.

So for example:
$$\left \{\begin{align}
x&\equiv 5\bmod{8} & \implies  x &\equiv 1\bmod 4\\
x&\equiv 7\bmod{12} & \implies  x &\equiv 3\bmod 4\\
\end{align}
\right .
$$
and thus no solutions.

If this check shows that solutions are possible, as here:
$$\left \{\begin{align}
x&\equiv 3\bmod{8} & \implies  x &\equiv 3\bmod 4\\
x&\equiv 7\bmod{12} & \implies  x &\equiv 3\bmod 4\\
\end{align}
\right .
$$
we could proceed (for cases not as amenable to simple examination) by noting that the first equivalence means that $x= 8k+3$ and thus
$\begin{align}
8k+3 &\equiv 7\bmod 12\\
8k &\equiv 4\bmod 12 \\
2k &\equiv 1\bmod 3 &\text{(divide through all by gcd)}\\
k &\equiv 2\bmod 3 \\
\therefore x &\equiv 8\cdot 2 +3 \equiv 19 \bmod 24
\end{align}$

Comment: You missed the $\pm 5$ symmetry - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:  it's $\ x\equiv \pm 5\bmod 8\ \&\ 12.$ We can't have $\,x\equiv -5,5\,$ or $\,5,-5\bmod 8,12$ else $\,x\equiv -1,1$ or $1,-1\bmod 4.\,$ So $\,x\equiv 5,5\,$ or $\,-5,-5\bmod 8,12\iff x\equiv \pm5\bmod 24,\,$ by $24={\rm lcm}(8,12)$

Comment: The final LCM inference is equivalent to CCRT = [Constant case of CRT.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)