# A discrepancy in the proof that 561 is Carmichael number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, congruence-relations

The proof is given below:

[image]

But I do not understand the statement in the line before last which says "These give rise to the single congruence $a ^{560} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ where gcd(a, 561) = 1 ", I do not know why the previous mentioned system of linear congruences leads to this single congruence, what theorem is used to say this? is it the Chinese Remainder theorem ? if so how?

Comment: Please don't post pictures: type the material. Pictures are not searchable, and can cause problems with sundry interfaces.

Comment: $a^{560}-1$ is divisible by $3$, by $11$ and by $17$.

Comment: Yes, it's the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The 3 congruences yield a unique solution modulo $3\times 11\times 17$; setting $x=a^{560}$, you get the unique solution $x\equiv 1\pmod{561}$ (because clearly that is a solution to the system, and by the CRT, it's the **unique** solution to the system modulo $561$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That is just what I was going to put.

Comment: You can use properties of LCM, Euclid's Lemma, unique factorization, or CCRT = Constant-case CRT to make that inference - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) which explains all four methods.

Comment: Ok I will follow this as long as I have enough time ..... sorry about this @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a^{560}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $3,11,$ and $17$, you know that $a^{560}-1$ is divisible by $3,11,$ and $17$. Thus, since $3,11,$ and $17$ are mutually coprime, $a^{560}-1$ is divisible by $3\cdot 11\cdot 17=561$ and so $a^{560}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $561$.

Answer (score 2):

The previous equations say that the integers $3,11$ and $17$ all divide $a^{560}-1$. This implies that their lcm must divide $a^{560}-1$ as well. But since $3,11,17$ are relatively prime their lcm is just their product which is $561$. So $561$ divides $a^{560}-1$, which means $a^{560}\equiv 1$(mod $561$).

Comment: I like that this answer does not require the use of CRT.  However, stylistically the proof in the OP does assume the reader’s familiarity with CRT (one immediately sees that *some* congruence of this shape holds, and that the precise value of the RHS can be verified very easily with almost no computation).

Answer (score 2):

You can see this as a consequence of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Setting $x=a^{560}$, you have a system that says
$$\begin{align*}
x&\equiv 1\pmod{3}\\
x&\equiv 1\pmod{11}\\
x&\equiv 1\pmod{17}
\end{align*}$$
By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a unique solution modulo $3\times 11\times 17$, that is, $x\equiv b\pmod{561}$. But clearly, $b=1$ is a solution, so that is the unique solution. Hence $a^{560}=x\equiv 1\pmod{561}$.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* indeed the chinese remainder theorem:

> **Chinese remainder Theorem**
>
> If a system of equations
>
> $x \equiv a_i \mod m_i$ for some $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, with pairwise coprime $m_i$, then there is a unique solution mod $m_1m_2\cdots m_n$

Applying this to $m_1=3,m_2=11,m_3=17$ and $a_1=a_2=a_3=1$ gives the desired result.