# What is the remainder of $3\text{^}(15\text{^}2019)$ when divided by $29$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I think you are supposed to use Fermat's little theorem but I don't know how to apply it. I tried using exponent laws but I don't know about any such laws that work in this scenario.

Comment: Edit: I flattened the exponents in title, we try to keep titles not too vertically demanding.

Answer (score 0):

$$F=3^{15^{2n+1}}\equiv3^{15^{2n+1}\pmod{28}}\pmod{29}$$

Now $15^2\equiv1\pmod{28}$

$$\implies F\equiv3^{15(1)^n}\pmod{29}$$

Now $3^3\equiv-2\pmod{29}$

$\implies3^{15}=(3^3)^5\equiv(-2)^5\equiv-3\equiv-3+29$

Comment: i.e. Fermat $\Rightarrow 3^{\large\color{#0a0}{28}}\!\equiv1\pmod{\!29}\,$ so $\,3^{\large 15^{\Large N}}\!\!\!\equiv 3^{\large 15^{\Large N}\!\bmod \color{#0a0}{28}}\,$ by [modular order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242). By [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242) $\,15^{\large\color{#c00} 2}\equiv 1\pmod{\!28}^{\phantom{|^{|^|}}}\!\!$ by $\,15^{\large\color{#c00}2}\!\equiv (\pm1)^2\equiv1 \pmod{\!4\ \&\ 7},\,$ so $\,15^{N}\!\equiv 15^{\large N\bmod\color{#c00}2}\pmod{\!28}\ \ $