# Prove that $3^{500} + 5$ is divisible by $14$ using theory of congruences.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Number theory question, based on the theory of congruences.

Comment: 3^500 ≡ -5 mod 14

Comment: How have you tried to attack the problem?

Comment: Clearly $\,2\mid 3^{6k+2}+5 =: n,\,$ and $7\mid n\,$ by $\!\bmod 7\!:\ 3^{6k+2}\equiv (\color{#c00}{3^6})^k 3^2\equiv \color{#c00}1\cdot 9.\,$ So $\,2,7\mid n\Rightarrow 2\cdot 7\mid n\,$ by [lcm/CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190522/242)

Comment: Or use $\,(a,14)=1\Rightarrow a^6\equiv 1\pmod{14}\,$ by the 4th dupe (my answer there shows this method generalizes widely).

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$3^3=27\equiv -1\mod 14$$

$$500=3\times 166+2$$

Remark

You can use Euler's Theorem
$$gcd(3,14)=1\implies $$
$$3^{\phi(14)}\equiv 1 \mod 14$$

with
$$\phi(14)=14(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 17)=6$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry for that,  Next time, i will ask you first.

Answer (score 1):

$2$ divides $3^{500}+5$, because $3^{500}+5\equiv1^{500}+5\equiv0\pmod 2$.

$7$ divides $3^{500}+5$, because $3^6\equiv1\pmod7$ (by Fermat's little theorem),

so $3^{498}\equiv1\pmod7 $, so $3^{500}+5\equiv3^2+5\equiv0\pmod7$.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.