# The least number which leaves remainders 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 on dividing by 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 is

Tags: number-theory

**Problem** - The least number which leaves remainders 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 on dividing by 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 is?

**Solution** - Here 3-2 = 1, 4-3 = 1, 5-4 = 1 and so on.

So required number is (LCM of 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) - 1 = 419

**My confusion** -

I didn't get the solution of this. Please explain how by subtracting the conclusion was drawn that the number will be the (LCM - 1)?

Answer (score 2):

$\, x\!+\!1\equiv 0\pmod{m_i}\iff  m_i\mid x\!+\!1\iff {\rm lcm}\{m_i\}\mid x\!+\!1\iff x\equiv -1\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{m_i\}}$

Or, equivalently: $\,\ x\equiv -1\pmod{m_i}\iff x\equiv -1\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{m_i\}},\ $ whihc may be viewed as the special [*constant-case* of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73541/242)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/731302/134937) in another similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731299/find-the-least-value-of-x-which-when-divided-by-3-leaves-remainder-1)

And this explain it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see by inspection that -1 works. Then any other solution must be congruent to -1 mod lcm(3,4,5,6,7) = 420 and hence the least positive solution is 419.