# Find the smallest number which leaves remainder 1, 2 and 3 when divided by 11, 51 and 91

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

While my preparation for exams, came across this question.

> "Find the smallest number which leaves remainder 1,2 and 3 when divided by 11,51 and 91"

Find considerable time in solving this. I have also gone through similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731299/find-the-least-value-of-x-which-when-divided-by-3-leaves-remainder-1).

This [site](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=388#top) gives answer for this question as 1277 with a detailed strategy. can this be used as a reliable approach or is there better approach available. Please advice so that I can start solving such problems

EDIT:Adding relevant portions of the answer cited for clarity

How  (51051/11)y1 ≡ 1 (mod 11) can be written in the following block?

```
x ≡ 1 (mod 11)      
x ≡ 2 (mod 51)   
x ≡ 3 (mod 91)

11,51,91 are positive integers and pairwise co-prime.  Hence, as per Chinese remainder theorem, there is exactly one number between 1 and 11×51×91 = 51051 that meets all these criteria

N = 11×51×91 = 51051

(51051/11)y1 ≡ 1 (mod 11)
```

After finding y1, y2 and y3, how the following line can be written for finding x?

```
x = 1 × (51051/11) × 10 + 2 × (51051/51) × 8 + 3 × (51051/91) × 85   mod 51051
```

I could relate other concepts from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: thx, got the solution. It was nothing but Chinese Remainder Theorem

Comment: How does crt give the smallest answer, doesn't it give all the answers?

Comment: @jeea but if one knows all the answers then I guess one could find the smallest right?

Answer (score 1):

Using [CRT](https://www.dcode.fr/chinese-remainder) (as it seems you have done) you should find the solution set given by
$$x = 51051k + 1277$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, to find the smallest possible solution take $k = 0$ and we have that $1277$ is the smallest solution.

It looks like you found that $$x = (51051/11) \cdot 10 + 2 \cdot (51051/51) \cdot 8 + 3 \cdot (51051/91)\cdot 85 \pmod {51051}$$

so you only need to reduce $\pmod {51051}$:

\begin{align}
x &= 205481 \pmod {51051}\\
  &= 1277 \pmod {51051}
\end{align}