# Quadratic residue with CRT ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm given $$x^2\equiv a \pmod q$$ where $q=p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3$

I've rewrite it in a system of three and used the CRT on it and got a solution, but in the system I used $x$ instead of $x^2$.

Should have I done it with $x^2$ ? Because my solution doesn't work for the origin equation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You ask "is my solution correct?" but don't give your solution.

Comment: Sorry, you're right !

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:OK, in general, if I want to use the CRT on a quadratic residue , should I use $x$ or $x^2$?

Comment: Let’s see your proposed solution to the problem, then one can attempt to judge its correctness.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137251/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1262457/242) for some worked examples.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Thanks!!