# Find the remainder when $f(x)$ divided by $(x^2 + x + 1)(x+1)$.

Tags: polynomials

When a polynomial $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2 + x + 1$ and $(x+1)^2$, the remainder are $x+5$ and $x-1$ respectively. Find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x^2 + x + 1)(x+1)$.

First, I let the remainder be $Ax^2 + Bx +C$, then I try to find the values of $A$, $B$ and $C$. There is $3$ unknowns so we need three equations but I can only get two equations.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Which equations did you get, and how did you get them? Also note that an equation like $5x + 3 = Ax+B$ is actually two-in-one, since what we have is an equality of _functions_, so each coefficient must be equal. I assume that will give you the third one you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ f = x\!+\!5 + \color{#c00}c\,(\overbrace{x^2\!+\!x\!+\!1}^{\large g})\ $ and $\ {-}2 = \color{#0a0}{f\bmod x\!+\!1} = f(-1) = 4\!+\!c\iff \color{#c00}{c = -6}$

See [this Remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) for more detail, and the relationship to CRT and Lagrange interpolation.

---

**Remark** $\:\!\ $ Or use $\,\ fg\bmod hg\, =\, [f\bmod h]\,g\,= $  [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2021696/242) $ $  *algorithmically*

$$\,\ \ \begin{align}
f-(x\!+\!5)\ \bmod\ (x\!+\!1)g\,
 =\ &\left[\dfrac{f-(x\!+\!5)}{g}\bmod\, x\!+\!1\right]g\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \ \ f\equiv x\!+\!5\!\!\!\pmod{\!g}\\[.3em]
=\ &\left[\dfrac{f(-1)-4}{1}\right]g\ \ \ \,{\rm by}\ \ \ g\bmod x\!+\!1 = g(-1) = 1\\[.3em]
=\ &[\color{#c00}{\,-6}\,]\,g\ \ \ {\rm by}\ \  f(-1)=\color{#0a0}{f\bmod x\!+\!1} = x\!-\!1\bmod x\!+\!1 = -2
\end{align}$$

Note that we did not need to solve any equations - only evaluate polynomials at $\,x=-1$
The same method works generally:

**Lemma** $\,\  \bbox[7px,border:1px solid #c00]{f\bmod (x\!-\!a)g\, =\, f_g + \left[\dfrac{f(a)- f_g(a)}{g(a)}\right]g}\ \ $ if $\ g(a)\neq 0,\,$ for $\,f_g := f\bmod g$

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\ \ \ \ 
f-f_g\ \bmod\ (x\!-\!a)g\,
 =\ &\left[\dfrac{f-f_g}{g}\bmod\, x\!-\!a\right]g\\[.3em]
 =\ &\left[\dfrac{f(a)-f_g(a)}{g(a)}\right]g
\end{align}$

The  formula does not require solving equations, only evaluating a few polynomials at $\,x=a$

**Note** $ $ The $\!\bmod\!$ Distributive Law can be viewed as an equivalent "shifty" operational reformulation  of  CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem, as I explain in the end of my [Remark here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137251/242) It is often more convenient to apply in practice because of its operational nature, e.g. [here are many examples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+mod+distributive+law+)

Answer (score 0):

We know that
$$f(x)=Q_1(x)(x^2 + x + 1)+x+5=Q_2(x)(x+1)^2+x-1$$
for some polynomials $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.
Moreover, for some polynomial $Q_3$,
$$f(x)=Q_3(x)(x^2 + x + 1)(x+1)+Ax^2+Bx+C.$$
Hence
$$f(-1)=-1-1=A(-1)^2+B(-1)+C.$$
Now consider the complex zeros $w_1$ and $w_2$ of $x^2 + x + 1$. Then
$$f(w_1)=w_1+5=Aw_1^2+Bw_1+C\quad,\quad f(w_2)=w_2+5=Aw_2^2+Bw_2+C.$$
By solving the linear system of the three equations we find that $A = -6$, $B = -5$, $C = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$p(x)\equiv (x-1)\pmod{(x+1)^2} $$
implies $p(x)\equiv (x-1) \equiv -2 \pmod{(x+1)}$. We know that $p(x)\equiv(x+5)\pmod{x^2+x+1}$, or
$$ p(x) = (x+5) + (x^2+x+1) r(x) $$
hence
$$ p(x) \equiv 4 + r(x)\pmod{(x+1)}$$
and $r(x)\equiv -6\pmod{(x+1)}$. It follows that
$$ p(x) = (x+5)+(x^2+x+1)(-6+(x+1)s(x)) $$
and
$$ p(x)\equiv \color{red}{(x+5)-6(x^2+x+1)} \pmod{(x+1)(x^2+x+1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The remainder when dividing by $(x+1)^2$ was $x-1$, so the remainder when dividing by just $x+1$ must be $-2$.

We know that $f(x)$ is of the form
$$
f(x) = q(x)(x^2 + x + 1)(x+1) + Ax^2 + Bx + C
$$
where $q(x)$ is a polynomial and $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ has the same remainders as $f$ does when divided by $x+1$ and by $x^2 + x + 1$. Now we just calculate:
$$
\frac{Ax^2 + Bx + C}{x+1} = Ax + B-A+\frac{C-B+A}{x+1}
$$
so we must have $C-B+A = -2$. That's one equation down. Now we deal with $x^2 + x + 1$:
$$
\frac{Ax^2 + Bx + C}{x^2 + x + 1} = Ax + \frac{(B-A)x + C-A}{x^2 + x + 1}
$$
so we know that $(B-A)x + C-A = x+5$. As I alluded to in the comments to the question above, this is actually two equations in one, as this is an equality of *functions*. The slopes must be equal, and the constant terms must be equal. This gives you the remaining two equations $B-A = 1$ and $C-A = 5$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Generalized Euclidean Algorithm, we get
$$
(x+2)\left(x^2+x+1\right)-(x+1)(x+1)^2=1\tag1
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(x+2)\left(x^2+x+1\right)&\equiv1&&\pmod{(x+1)^2}\\
(x+2)\left(x^2+x+1\right)&\equiv0&&\pmod{x^2+x+1}
\end{align}\tag2
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
-(x+1)(x+1)^2&\equiv0&&\pmod{(x+1)^2}\\
-(x+1)(x+1)^2&\equiv1&&\pmod{x^2+x+1}
\end{align}\tag3
$$
Thus, to get
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)&\equiv x-1&&\pmod{(x+1)^2}\\
f(x)&\equiv x+5&&\pmod{x^2+x+1}
\end{align}\tag4
$$
we can use $x-1$ times $(2)$ plus $x+5$ times $(3)$ to get $\bmod{(x+1)^2\left(x^2+2x+1\right)}$
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&\equiv(x-1)(x+2)\left(x^2+x+1\right)-(x+5)(x+1)(x+1)^2\\
&=-6x^3-18x^2-17x-7\\
&\equiv-6x^2-5x-1\pmod{(x+1)\left(x^2+2x+1\right)}\tag5
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Readers No doubt we can *mechanically* solve any congruence system using one of the many formulations of CRT (e.g. the above Bezout-based method). But computing it mechanically typically inhibits optimizations that exploit any innate special structure that the problem may possess - structure which may yield *significant* simplifications. For example. here one of the moduli is *linear*, which greatly simplifies matters - reducing the computation to a single line, e.g. see my answer.

Comment: Also worth emphasis: the algebra in $(2)$ thru $(6)$ is a special case of a [simple general method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3177321/242) for transforming the moduli gcd Bezout equation into a CRT solution, viz. **scale the Bezout equation for the moduli gcd by the residue difference** $\,\color{#c00}{x+5-(\color{#0a0}{x-1}) = 6}\,$ **then rearrange**,

$$\ \ \qquad\qquad\begin{align}(\color{#c00}{x+5-}(\color{#0a0}{x-1}))\,1\,=\,\color{#c00}6\,((x+2)(x^2+x+1)\color{#0a0}{-(x+2)(x+1)^2})\\[.3em]
\iff f \,\equiv\, x+5 -6(x^2+x+1)\,\equiv\, \color{#0a0}{x-1-6(x+2)(x+1)^2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $$ f(x)=k(x)(x^2+x+1)+x+5$$

and $$ f(x)=q(x)(x+1)^2+x-1 \Longrightarrow f(-1) = -2$$

So $$-2 = f(-1) = k(-1)\cdot 1 +4 \Longrightarrow k(-1) = -6$$

thus

$$ k(x) = p(x)(x+1)-6 $$ and finally 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &= &(p(x)(x+1)-6)(x^2+x+1)+x+5 \\
&=& p(x)(x+1)(x^2+x+1)-6x^2-5x-1
\end{eqnarray}