# How to solve for these two values - square root modulo composite and Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to solve for 188 and 131, how do we get 188 and 131 using CRT?

I can calculate these, its just I do not get how to get 188 and 131.

```
√23 (mod 209)

√a (mod p) = ±a(p+1)/4, if p ≡ 3 (mod 4)

√4 (mod 11) = ±23^3(mod 11) = ±1

√4 (mod 11) = ±23^3(mod 11) = ±17
```

Using the CRT we can therefore calculate √
23 (mod 209) as ±188, ±131

Comment: You combine the solutions mod $11$ and $19$ using CRT exactly as described in the duplicate. If that is not clear then ping me here and I will elaborate.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate, exactly?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1864763/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2137251/242) for more worked examples.

Comment: We seek solutions to $\,x\equiv a\equiv \pm1\pmod{\!11},\ x\equiv b\equiv \pm2\pmod{\!19}.\,$ Applying CRT wwe find a solution for $\,a,b = -1,2\,$ is $\,x\equiv 21\pmod{\!209}$ and its negative (corresponding to $\,a,b = 1,-2)$

Comment: Similarly $\,a,b = 1,2\,$ yields $\,x\equiv 78\pmod{\!209}\,$ and its negative (for $\,a,b = -1,-2)\ $

Comment: $\!\bmod 209\!:\,\ 21 \equiv -188\ $ and $\,78\equiv -131\ $ so these are the same as your solutions.  Thos are all the possible combinatios of roots mod $11$ and roots mod $19$ so those are all the possible roots mod $11\cdot 19$ by the CRT argument in the linked threads.

Comment: could you elaborate about the combination of solutions of mod 11 and 19?

Comment: @hashsaltpepper That's explained in the linked dupe, see "By CRT each combination..."