# Understanding the $\equiv$ symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I am trying to understand a wierd symbol in a book and I am failing.

The symbol is this '$\equiv$'. I understood that if I have $32\equiv 2\bmod15$ means that if I divide $32$ with $15$ I will get $2$ as a remainder.

What if for example if i have

$$x\equiv 5 \bmod17$$ and
$$x\equiv 3 \bmod23$$

How to find if there is such $x$ that satisfies both cases?

Comment: "in a book" - which book?

Comment: What you need here is the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: It is called "Discrete Mathematics for beginners" but I think it is only available in my language.

Comment: It is still important that you mention where you saw notation you're unfamiliar with whenever you ask questions like these. Even if the source isn't English.

Answer (score 5):

The general meaning of '$\equiv$' is an equivalence relation.  In elementary number theory the notation (due to Gauss) has the specific meaning of equivalent "modulo" an integer, namely:

$$x \equiv y \pmod{n}$$

means that $(x-y)$ is divisible by $n$.

A basic set of exercises in an elementary number theory course is to prove that this relation between integers $x,y$ is an equivalence relation for any $n \gt 0$.  For $n=0$ it may be a convention to consider the notation as amounting to ordinary equality of integers.

Comment: So $(x-5)/17 = 0$ and $(x-3)/23=0$ which means $x=32/3$?

Comment: @hardmath: I edited your post using the "\pmod" command.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @vellosoum: Not quite. $x\equiv 5\pmod{17}$ means that $x-5$ is divisible by $17$, so there is some integer $k$ such that $x-5=17k$. Similarly, $x\equiv 3\pmod{23}$ means that there is some integer $j$ such that $x-3=23j$. Thus, $x=17k+5=23j+3$, and $23j=17k+2$. This has infinitely many integer solutions, and each of them gives rise to a different solution to the original pair of congruences.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Then why the book expects a value for an answer?

Comment: @vellosoum: Your text ought to have an example of such a problem, or at least a discussion of the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (or see [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/chinese.shtml)), but you can find a solution by hand. In this case a little experimentation shows that $8\cdot 17+2=6\cdot 23$, so $k=8,j=6,x=141$ is one solution. Adding or subtracting integer multiples of $17\cdot 23$ will produce others. There is only one solution satisfying $0\le x<17\cdot 23$; if it wants just one solution, that’s probably it.

Answer (score 1):

As JM says, you can use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to solve this kind of question.  You have

- $x\equiv 5 \bmod17$ so $x = 17k +5$ for some $k$
- $x\equiv 3 \bmod23$ so $x = 23j +3$ for some $k$

so you can look for solutions to $17 k+5=23j+3$ or equivalently $2\equiv 23j \bmod17$ which can be simplified to $2\equiv 6j \bmod17$ since $23\equiv 6 \bmod17$.

One possibility is $j=6$ since $36\equiv 2 \bmod17$, making $x=141$.  To check: $141 = 8 \times 17+5 = 6\times 23+3$.

Since $17$ and $23$ are coprime, and $17\times 23 = 391$, the general solution is $141+391n$ for integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

An ancient algorithm known as the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) solves systems of congruences. Using a simple version that I [mention here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242), since $\rm\:gcd(17,23) = 1\:$ we know $\rm\:1/23\:$ exists $\rm\:mod\ 17\:,\:$ and employing it easily yields the following solution

$$\rm\ x\ \equiv\ 3\ +\ (5-3)\cdot 23\cdot \bigg(\ \dfrac{1}{23}\ mod\ 17\bigg)\quad\ (mod\ 17\cdot 23) $$

Notice that, indeed, $\rm\ x\: \equiv\: 3\pmod{23}\:;\ $ also $\rm\ x\:\equiv\: 3 + (5-3)\:\equiv\: 5\pmod{17}\:,\: $ using $\ 23\cdot 23^{-1}\equiv 1\:.\ $ It remains to compute the modular inverse, which is easy with a little modular massaging

$$\rm mod\ 17\!:\ \ \frac{1}{23}\ \equiv\ \frac{18}{6}\ \equiv\ 3$$

Therefore we conclude $\rm\ x\ \equiv\ 3 + (5-3)\cdot 23\cdot 3\ \equiv 141\quad (mod\ 17\cdot 23)$

Generally one can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to compute modular inverses. However, as above, for small numbers there are often many nice coincidences (law of small numbers) that enable obvious optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here: One is about notation and the other one about the solution of a particular problem involving this notation.

(a) The symbol $\equiv$ implying some sort of "equality" or "equivalence" is used in everyday mathematics in two completely different frameworks. In analysis an  "identity" of the form

$$\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x\ \equiv\ 1$$

conveys the meaning that the equation $\sin^2 x+\cos^2x =1$ is true for all values of the variable $x$ in the actual environment of discourse, say $\bigl[0,{\pi\over2}\bigr]$, ${\mathbb R}$, or ${\mathbb C}$.

In elementary number theory the symbol $\equiv$ in an equation only has a meaning in connection with an attribute "$(\bmod m)$" stated explicitly on the right of the equation. An equation of the form $x\equiv y \pmod m$ then means that $x-y$ is divisible by the integer $m$. One might as well write an $m$ below the $\equiv$-symbol.

It follows that in your example the symbol $\equiv$ means different things in the two given equations.

(b) Concerning the particular problem I refer to other answers to your question.