# Chinese Remainder theorem with non-pairwise coprime moduli

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, arithmetic

Let $n_1,...,n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $a_1,...,a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
How to prove the following version of the Chinese remainder theorem ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement)):

There exists a $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying system of equations:
$$x=a_1 \pmod {n_1}$$
$$x=a_2  \pmod {n_2}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$x=a_k \pmod{n_k}$$
if and only if $a_i=a_j \pmod{\gcd(n_i,n_j)}$ for all $i,j=1,...,k$?

If numbers $n_i$, for $i=1,...,k$, are pairwise coprime, it is a classical version of Chinese remainder theorem.

Thanks.

Comment: Try $k=2$ and then induction.

Comment: I think your penultimate sentence should talk about $n_i$ being pairwise coprime, not $a_i$.

Comment: Title edit suggestion: *"Proof of a Chinese Remainder Theorem with non-coprime moduli".*

Comment: Tag suggestion: number-theory

Comment: @Richard - Look up my answer to the (duplicate) [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911902).

Comment: In case anyone finds this question and is interested.
A proof (basically the same as in the accepted answer) is given in the book "Elementary Number Theory" (Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series), by Gareth A. Jones and J. Mary Jones.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If we factor $n_k$ into primes, $n_k = p_{1}^{b_{1}}\cdots p_r^{b_{r}}$, then the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that $x\equiv a_k\pmod{n_k}$ is equivalent to the system of congruences
$$\begin{align*}
x&\equiv a_k\pmod{p_1^{b_{1}}}\\
x&\equiv a_k\pmod{p_2^{b_{2}}}\\
&\vdots\\
x&\equiv a_k\pmod{p_r^{b_{r}}}
\end{align*}$$
Thus, we can replace the given system of congruences with one in which every modulus is a prime power, $n_i = p_i^{b_i}$.

Note that the assumption that $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod{\gcd(n_i,n_j)}$ "goes through" this replacement (if they were congruend modulo $\gcd(n_i,n_j)$, then they are congruent modulo the gcds of the prime powers as well).

So, we may assume without loss of generality that every modulus is a prime power.

I claim that we can deal with each prime separately, again by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. If we can solve all congruences involving the prime $p_1$ to obtain a solution $x_1$ (which will be determined modulo the highest power of $p_1$ that occurs); and all congruences involving the prime $p_2$ to obtain a solution $x_2$ (which will be determined modulo the highest power of $p_2$ that occurs); and so on until we obtain a solution $x_n$ for all congruences involving the prime $p_n$ (determined modulo the highest power of $p_n$ that occurs), then we can obtain a simultaneous solution by solving the usual Chinese Remainder Theorem system
$$\begin{align*}
x &\equiv x_1 \pmod{p_1^{m_1}}\\
&\vdots\\
x &\equiv x_n\pmod{p_n^{m_n}}
\end{align*}$$
(where $m_i$ is the highest power of $p_i$ that occurs as a modulus).

So we are reduced to solving figuring out whether we can solve the system
$$\begin{align*}
x &\equiv a_1\pmod{p^{b_1}}\\
x &\equiv a_2\pmod{p^{b_2}}\\
&\vdots\\
x & \equiv a_n\pmod{p^{b_n}}
\end{align*}$$
with, without loss of generality, $b_1\leq b_2\leq\cdots\leq b_n$.

When can this be solved? Clearly, this can be solved if and only if $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod{p^{b_{\min(i,j)}}}$: any solution must satisfy this condition, and if this condition is satisfied, then $a_n$ is a solution.

For example: say the original moduli had been $n_1 = 2^3\times 3\times 7^2$, $n_2= 2^2\times 5\times 7$, $n_3=3^2\times 5^3$. First we replace the system with the system of congruences
$$\begin{align*}
x&\equiv a_1 \pmod{2^3}\\
x&\equiv a_2\pmod{2^2}\\
x&\equiv a_1\pmod{3}\\
x&\equiv a_3\pmod{3^2}\\
x&\equiv a_2\pmod{5}\\
x&\equiv a_3\pmod{5^3}\\
x&\equiv a_1\pmod{7^2}\\
x&\equiv a_2\pmod{7}.
\end{align*}$$
Then we separately solve the systems:
$$\begin{align*}
x_1&\equiv a_1 \pmod{2^3} &x_2&\equiv a_1\pmod{3}\\
x_1&\equiv a_2\pmod{2^2}&x_2&\equiv a_3\pmod{3^2}\\
\strut\\
x_3&\equiv a_2\pmod{5}&x_4&\equiv a_1\pmod{7^2}\\
x_3&\equiv a_3\pmod{5^3}&x_4&\equiv a_2\pmod{7}.
\end{align*}$$

Assuming we can solve these, $x_1$ is determined modulo $2^3$, $x_2$ modulo $3^2$, $x_3$ modulo $5^3$, and $x_4$ modulo $7^2$, so we then solve the system
$$\begin{align*}
x &\equiv x_1\pmod{2^3}\\
x &\equiv x_2\pmod{3^2}\\
x&\equiv x_3 \pmod{5^3}\\
x&\equiv x_4\pmod{7^2}
\end{align*}$$
and obtain a solution to the original system.

Hence, if the condition $a_i\equiv a_j\pmod{\gcd(n_i,n_j)}$ holds in the original system, then we obtain a solution for each prime, and from the solution for each prime we obtain a solution to the original system by applying the usual Chinese Remainder Theorem twice.

Comment: This is written up nicely and I can't seem to find it anywhere else so +1,000