# Chinese Remainder Theorem when n values are not coprime?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, euclidean-algorithm, coprime

$$ x\equiv 2 \mod 20 $$
$$ x\equiv 7 \mod 15 $$

setting $a \equiv  b \mod n$
how would you approach this as the two $n$ values are not coprime?

I've broken down the $ 7\bmod15 $ into $x\equiv 7\mod3$ and $x\equiv 7\mod5$ so could treat it as simultaneous with three equations but I didn't know where to go from here?

Comment: break down $x\equiv2\bmod20$ into two congruences too

Comment: The full statement of Chinese Remainder Theorem applies to any (finite) number of simultaneous congruences.

Comment: This tells you the congruence mod $20$ and mod $3$, which is enough to give you the congruence mod $60$.

Comment: See "General Easy CRT" in the linked dupe for a simple formula that requires only efficient gcd calculations (vs. expensive prime factorizations in some other methods).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Breaking also the congruence modulo $20$ leads to this system of congruences with pairwise coprime moduli:
\begin{cases}
x\equiv7\equiv 1\mod 3,\\
x\equiv 2\mod 4, \\
x\equiv 7\equiv 2\mod 5.
\end{cases}
Solve the first two congruences to obtain a congruence modulo $12$ and group the latter with the congruence modulo $5$.

Answer (score -1):

Just because the $n$ values share a common factor doesn't mean that you can't apply CRT. If you get a contradiction such as $x \equiv 1 \pmod 6, x  \equiv 2 \pmod {15}$ which imply $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $x = 2 \pmod 3$, then there is no solution. However, you can always break down $n$ into its prime factors, as you can see in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095442).

You can directly substitute the second into the first, which gives $15k + 7 \equiv 2 \pmod {20}$, or $15k \equiv -5 \pmod {20} \implies 3k \equiv -1 \pmod {4}$. This gives $3k \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ or $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Thus the general solution is $15(4k + 1) + 7 = 60k + 22$, where $60$ is the greatest common divisor of $15$ and $20$.