# An 'away sheaf' on the scheme of a PID: Localize at powers of the generator of the prime ideal?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, schemes, localization

$\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$
$\newcommand{\p}{\mathfrak{p}}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}$
$\newcommand{\mmod}{\operatorname{mod}}$

**Background:**

Consider a principal ideal domain $R$. The usual structure sheaf on the scheme
$\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ defines the ring of functions at each point $\p \in
\Spec R$ to be $R$ localized at $S := R\setminus \p$. This localization turns $R$ into a
local ring, with $\p$ as a maximal ideal.

On the other hand, since $R$ is a PID, let $\p$ be generated by an element
$\p_0 \in R$. So we have $\p = (\p_0)$. We can build a different sheaf on
$\Spec(R)$ (call it  the **away sheaf**) which assigns to a point $\p \in \Spec(R)$, $R$ localized at $S
:= \{ 1, \p_0, \p_0^2, \dots \}$.  This localization annihilates all information
"at $\p$", and carries information only about what happens "away from $\p$".

For example, let $R = \Z/30\Z$. The primes in this
ring are $(2), (3), (5)$. If we consider the "function" $21$
on the usual structure sheaf,
we get the local components $21(\p) = 21_{R\setminus \p}$: the residue of $21$
when the ring is localized at the ring $\p$. This gives
$21(2) = 1, 21(3) = 0, 21(5) = 1$. By chinese remainder, we can
find the original number $21$.

On the other hand, let us consider the away sheaf on the same ring
$\Z/30\Z$. It assigns the
values $21((\p_0)) = 21_{R \setminus S}$ where $S = \{1, \p_0, \p_0^2, \dots \}$:
the residue of $21$ on ignoring the prime $\p_0$. This gives values
$21(2) = 6, 21(3) = 1, 21(5) = 3$. That is, we consider:

- $21(2) = 21 ~(\mmod 30/2) = 21 ~(\mmod 15) = 6$
- $21(3) = 21 ~(\mmod 30/3) = 21 ~(\mmod 10) = 1$
- $21(5) = 21 ~(\mmod 30/5)  = 21~(\mmod 6)= 3$

To glue together the data, we solve the equations using [CRT for non
pairwise coprime moduli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120070/chinese-remainder-theorem-with-non-pairwise-coprime-moduli). Our residues will be consistent
because they came from a single number. Alternatively, the "full GCD"
of the numbers $\gcd(15, 10, 6) = 1$ thus we can always find a unique
solution.

In general, this technique works because for a given number $n = \prod_i p_i$,
we are finding the "away factors" $a_i \equiv n/p_i = \prod_{j \neq i} p_j$.
Then we will have $\gcd(a_1, \dots, a_k) = 1$ because each $a_i$ is missing
one of the primes $p_i$. This will allow us to recover solutions and glue
solutions together using CRT.

It's a very different kind of sheaf from the usual, beacuse we localize
using the multiples of the generator of the prime ideal, rather than localizing
using the complement of the prime ideal.

**Questions**:

1. This has surely been studied. What is this sort of phenomena called?
2. Are there more uses for this than just a curiosity?

**Verification**:

- [Here is the SAGE code I used to verify the localization computations.
  It prints the output of what happens when we localize at a multiplicative
  set.](https://gist.github.com/bollu/f999fcdb5e33cceeebf8159f1d3f29b4)

In this case, it provides the output:

```
Z/30Z localized at {2^i}:
   0 ->    0 | 1 ->    1
   2 ->    2 | 3 ->    3
   4 ->    4 | 5 ->    5
   6 ->    6 | 7 ->    7
   8 ->    8 | 9 ->    9
  10 ->   10 | 11 ->   11
  12 ->   12 | 13 ->   13
  14 ->   14 | 15 ->    0
  16 ->    1 | 17 ->    2
  18 ->    3 | 19 ->    4
  20 ->    5 | 21 ->    6
  ...
Z/30Z localized at complement of (2):
   0 ->    0 | 1 ->    1
   2 ->    0 | 3 ->    1
   4 ->    0 | 5 ->    1
   6 ->    0 | 7 ->    1
   ...
```

So the behaviour I claimed on localization is the behaviour that occurs.

Comment: You have not given enough data to define a sheaf. What are the sections over a general open set?

Comment: It's defined over distinguished open sets: one can always glue using compatible germs, right?

Comment: I don't see the definition in your post. You only said what you want the stalks to be – not only is that insufficient data to define a sheaf, it is not always possible to construct a sheaf with prescribed stalks. In this case there is a sheaf with the stalks you want but I'll let you work out what it is yourself.

Comment: Actually I confused myself. I don’t see how to construct a sheaf with the stalks you want.