# How to solve for multiple congruence's what aren't relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How could I go about solving 
$$x\equiv 1\mod 2$$
$$x\equiv 1\mod 3$$
$$x\equiv 1\mod 4$$
$$x\equiv 1\mod 5$$
$$x\equiv 1\mod 6$$
$$x\equiv 0\mod 7$$

I know that if I want to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem then I have to find a way for all the mod's to be relatively prime to each other but I am unsure which ones I can get rid of.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If $x \equiv 1 \mod {12}$ then $x \equiv 1 \mod {2,3,4,6}$.

So $x \equiv 1 \mod {60}$ and $x \equiv 0 \mod {7}$ does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

$x\equiv1\pmod4$ implies $x\equiv1\pmod2$, while $x\equiv1\pmod6$ is equivalent to the two congruences $x\equiv1\pmod2$ and $x\equiv1\pmod3$. So you should be okay keeping only the congruences modulo $3$, $4$, $5$, and $7$.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the system is equivalent to the following:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x & \equiv & 1 \qquad \mod \mathrm{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6) \\
x & \equiv & 0 \qquad \mod 7
\end{array}
$$
This way the Chinese remainder theorem is applicable.

Answer (score 2):

As a general comment, @user62015, a system of congruences with moduli that are not relatively prime can still have solutions. Take
$$
\begin{cases}
x \equiv a \pmod{m}\\
x \equiv b \pmod{n}
\end{cases}
$$
with $m,n$ not both zero.
If this has a solution $x$, then there are $s, t$ such that $a + ms = x = b + n t$, or
$$
b-a = ms - nt,
$$
so for a solution to exist we need $(m, n) \mid b - a$. Conversely, if $(m, n) \mid b - a$, use Euclid to find $u, v$ such that
$$
(m,n) = m u - n v,
$$
and multiply by the integer $(b-a)/(m,n)$ to get
$$
b-a = m (u (b-a)/(m,n)) - n (v (b-a)/(m,n)),
$$
so that 
$$
x = a + m (u (b-a)/(m,n)) = b + n (v (b-a)/(m,n))
$$ 
is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 1):

By [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) $\rm\ 2,3,4,5,6\mid x-1\iff 60 = lcm(2,3,4,5,6)\mid x-1\ $ so, by [Easy CRT,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) we have

$$\begin{array}{ll}\rm x\equiv 0\ \ (mod\ 7)\\ \rm x\equiv 1\ \ (mod\ 60)\end{array}\rm \!\iff x\equiv 1 + 60 \left[\frac{-1}{60}\ mod\ 7\right]\equiv -119,\ \ by\ \  mod\ 7\!:\, \frac{-1}{60}\equiv \frac{6}{-3}\equiv -2$$