# Solve $x \equiv 2$ mod 6 and $x \equiv 8$ mod 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have the following system of congruences: $$x \equiv 2 \, \text{mod 6}\\ x \equiv 8 \, \text{mod 9}$$
How do we solve this when $6$ and $9$ are not coprime? This excludes the use of CRT, unless we can rewrite the congruences in some clever fashion?

I hope you can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve for multiple congruence's what aren't relatively prime.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305745/how-to-solve-for-multiple-congruences-what-arent-relatively-prime) You can see the general strategy here, at least.

Comment: That is an old Brahmagupta problem which I've solved, simply throwing away the congruences that are equivalent (keeping only one). But here I cannot apply CRT without reducing. Does $x \equiv 2$ mod 6 imply $x \equiv 0$ mod 2, and does $x \equiv 8$ mod 9 imply $x \equiv 2$ mod 3?

I think it does. This way $(2,3)=1$ and we can use CRT?

Thanks for your reply by the way!

Comment: That sounds right to me, but I couldn't quote you a theorem.

Comment: By [CCRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2005579/242) $\,x\equiv 8\pmod{\!6\ \&\ 9}\iff x\equiv 8\pmod{\!18},\ $ by $18 ={\rm lcm}(6,9)$. **Or** apply  [general Easy CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have integers $n,k$ such that $x=6n+2=9k+8$. Then $2(n-1)=3k$
resulting in $n\equiv1\text{ mod }3$. Setting $n=3m+1$ gives you
$x=18m+8$, i.e. $x\equiv8\text{ mod }18$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. A typo. Restored now.

Comment: Now it's fine. +1

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @drhab Credit where credit is due. (+1)