# Euclid's algorithm - coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and $\operatorname{hcf}(m,n) = 1$, and suppose that $a$ and $b$ are integers with $0\le a\le m,\ 0\le b\le n$. How would you use Euclid's algorithm to find integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha m + \beta n = a-b$? Hence explain how to find an integer $N$ such that $N \equiv a \pmod{m}$ and $N \equiv b \pmod{n}$.

Comment: I guess the question or the answer is the Bezout identity.

Comment: I doubt that linear-algebra will be a relevant tag once the user completes the question.

Comment: The full text of the question is there, it just does not show (at least for me). If you try to edit,you'll see. If some kind soul would texify it...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Consider $\: N \,=\, a-\alpha\, m \,=\, b + \beta\, n\:$

To obtain $\ \alpha\,m + \beta\,n\, =\, a-b,\ $ scale the Bezout identity for $\ \gcd(m,n)=1\ $ by $\:a-b.\ $ Recall that the Bezout identity is easily computed by the [extended Euclidean algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500)

**Note** $\ $ Solving $\ \alpha\,m + \beta\,n\, =\, a-b\ $ for $\,\beta\,$ yields $\ \beta = (a-b)/n\pmod m,\ $  hence

$$\quad\ \ N \,\equiv\, b + \beta\, n \,\equiv\, b + n\ \left[ \dfrac{(a-b)}n\ {\rm mod}\ m\right]\!\!\pmod{mn}$$

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/23500) for more on this handy "Easy CRT" form of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The Bezout identity is a result of this

**Theorem**. hcf$(n, m) = d$ if and only if $\exists x, y\ (d = mx + ny)$

If you haven't seen the proof of this, you can look it up or ask here. It's a consequence of the Euclidean algorithm.

If we have integers $n, m$ such that hcf$(n, m) = 1$, the theorem tells us that we can find integers $x, y$ such that
$$
\begin{align}
1 &= mx+ny &\text{so}\\
a-b &=mx(a-b)+ny(a-b)\\
 &=m[x(a-b)]+n[y(a-b)]\\
 &= m\alpha+n\beta
\end{align}
$$
Then, as Math Gems observed, we'll have
$$
a-\alpha m =N= b+\beta n
$$
so $N\equiv a\pmod{m}$ and $N\equiv b\pmod{n}$.

---

**Example**. Take $m=8, n=3$. By the Euclidean algorithm we find
$$
1=8(2)+3(-5)\quad\text{so }x=2, y=-5
$$
and so, with $a=5, b=2$
$$
a-b = 3 =  8(6)+3(-15)\quad \text{so }\alpha=10, \beta=-15
$$
and observe that 
$$
a-\alpha m = 5-10\cdot 8 = -43 = 2 + -15\cdot 3 = b+\beta n \quad\text{so }N=-43
$$
and we have $-43\equiv 5\pmod{8}$ and $-43\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.

Comment: The Theorem is not stated correctly, because $\exists x,y(d=mx+ny)$ remains true if $d$ is replaced by any multiple of $d$. Perhaps you intended the right side of the "if and only if" to be "$d|m$ and $d|n$ and $\exists x,y(d=mx+ny)$.