# Chinese Remainder Theorem $\ x\equiv m_k-2\pmod{m_k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find all integers that give remainders 1,2,3 when divided by 3,4,5 respectively.  So I start defining 
$$a_1=1, a_2=2, a_3=3,$$$$ m_1=3, m_2=4, m_3=5,$$$$ m_1m_2=12, m_1m_3=15, m_2m_3=20,$$$$ m=60$$
All the moduli are pairwise coprime, so by the Euclidean Algorithm
$$12x+5y=1\Rightarrow x=-2, y=5.$$
$$15x+4y=1\Rightarrow x=-1, y=4.$$
$$20x+3y=1\Rightarrow x=-1, y=7.$$
Therefor a solution should be 
$$20\cdot(-2)\cdot1 +15\cdot (-1)\cdot 2+12\cdot (-1)\cdot 3=-40-30-36=-106$$
But under mod 60, this implies a solutions should be of the form, $60t+14$.  But it is not.  THis is not right.  Why did this technique not work?

Comment: It is in the form 60t+14. t=-2

Comment: No, the answer is wrong.  14 is not congruent to 1 mod 3 or 3 mod 5.  The correct answer should be 58 mod 60.

Comment: Sry. Mistook your last statement. Sorry

Comment: If i'm not mistaken (again), x=-2 and y=1 doesn't suit 12x+5y=1

Comment: $12x+5y=1\Rightarrow x=-2, y=1.$ should be $12x+5y=1\Rightarrow x=-2, y=5.$

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.  A typo...  But that doesn't help me much as I am using the $x$ values in the calculation...

Comment: @Lalaloopsy I expanded my answer with some remarks that may help you better understand the CRT formula, whic may help avoid such mixups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $\ 3,4,5\mid x+2\!\!\overset{\rm\color{#90f}U\!\!}\iff \overbrace{{\rm lcm}(3,4,5)}^{\large 60}\mid x+2 \iff {\rm mod}\ 60\!:\,\ x\equiv -2\equiv 58$

where we used $\,\rm\color{#90f}U = $ [lcm Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242). To find your error(s), check the answer mod $\,3,4,5,\,$ e.g. mod $\,3\!: x \equiv 20(-2)\equiv 2,\,$ not $1$. Looks like you mixed up the inverses in the final formula.

**Remark** $ $ Above I applied a simple reduction to the [constant case optimization of CRT.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242) $ $  If $\,x\equiv a_i\pmod {m_i}$ and $\,\color{#c00}{a_i - m_i = c}\,$ is *constant* (independent of $i),\,$  the system reduces to a simple *constant* case of CRT $\,\ x\equiv \color{#c00}{a_i \equiv m_i+c} \equiv c\pmod {m_i}.\,$  Therefore $$ x\equiv c\!\!\!\pmod {m_i}\iff m_i\mid x\!-\!c\!\!\overset{\rm\color{#90f}U\!\!}\iff {\rm lcm}\{m_i\}\mid x\!-\!c\iff x\equiv c\!\!\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{m_i\}}$$ Further examples of this and related optimizations can be found in [prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+crt+constant+case)

To help avoid such errors, it might help to understand better the key use of linearity at the heart of the  standard Chinese Remainder Theorem [CRT] formula.

$\quad \begin{eqnarray}
x\, =\, &a&\!\color{#0a0}{\overbrace{(4\cdot 5\ y_1)}^{\large \equiv\, 1\ ({\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}3)}} \,+\,  &b& \overbrace{(\color{#c00}3\cdot 5\ y_2)}^{\large \equiv\, 1\ ({\rm mod}\ 4)}\, +\, &c&\overbrace{(\color{#c00}3\cdot 4\  y_3)}^{\large \equiv\, 1\ ({\rm mod}\ 5)}\quad {\bf [CRT]}\\ \\
\Rightarrow\ \ x\,\equiv\, &a&\ ({\rm mod}\ \color{#c00}3),\ \ x\equiv &b&\ ({\rm mod}\ 4),\ \ x\equiv &c&\ ({\rm mod}\ 5)\\
\end{eqnarray}$

because, $ $ e.g., $\ $ mod $\ \color{#c00}3,\,$ the 2nd and 3rd summands are $\equiv 0,\,$ both having factors of $\,\color{#c00}3.\,$

Hence $\ x\,\equiv\, a\,\color{#0a0}{(4\cdot 5\ y_1)}\equiv  a\color{#0a0}{(1)} \equiv a\,\ ({\rm mod}\ 3),\, $  as desired. $ $ Similarly $ $ mod $\,4\,$ and $\,5.$

The **key idea** is that the braced terms are $\equiv 1$ mod one modulus, and $\equiv 0 $ mod all others. More clearly, if we write the system in *vector* form $\ x\equiv (a,b,c)\,$ mod $\,(3,4,5)$ then $\rm\,[CRT]$ becomes

$\quad x\, :=\, a\,\color{#0a0}{(1,0,0)} + b\,(0,1,0) + c\,(0,0,1)\equiv (a.b,c)\ $ as desired. $\qquad [\bf Linearity]$

by the green term $\,\color{#0a0}{g \equiv 1}\ ({\rm mod}\ 3),\ \color{#0a0}{g\equiv 0}\ ({\rm mod}\ 4),\  \color{#0a0}{g\equiv 0}\ ({\rm mod}\ 5),\ $ i.e. $\ \color{#0a0}{g\equiv (1,0,0)}\ {\rm mod}\ (3,4,5),\ $ and similarly for $\,(0,1,0)\,$ and $\,(0,0,1).$

Thus once we compute the solutions for the "basis" vectors $(1,0,0),\ (0,1,0),\ (0,0,1)$ we can exploit [Linearity] to generate the general solution as a linear combination of these solutions.

The innate algebraic structure will be clarified if you later study abstract algebra, where you will learn  the ring theoretic view of CRT, and vector spaces and modules.

Comment: I know the answers, but the technique I used above worked for numerous other examples.  Why is it not working for me this time?

Comment: Can you explain more about this technique you are referring to? Does it come from a book?

Comment: Yes, from Niven.  The technique is to form a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{m}{m_i}b_ia_i}$, where $\frac{m}{m_i}b_i\equiv 1\pmod{m_i}$.  I found the $b_i$ using linear combinations $m_im_jx+m_ky=1$.  I then set $x=b_i$.

Comment: @Nicky If $\,x\equiv a_i\pmod {m_i}$ and $\,\color{#c00}{m_i - a_i = c}\,$ is *constant* (doesn't depend on $i),\,$ then the system reduces to a simple *constant* case of CRT $\,\ x\equiv \color{#c00}{a_i \equiv m_i-c} \equiv -c\pmod {m_i}.\,$  Above $\,c = 2.\ \ $

Comment: @Lalaloopsy Nicky is not asking about that general form of CRT but, rather, the constant-case optimization that I applied in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

About the error: A couple of numbers got transposed. It should be $(20)(-1)(1)+(15)(-1)(2)+(12)(-2)(3)$.

Comment: I went back and saw where I made my mistake.  I looked at each $b_i$ and realized they were with the wrong modulus.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. It is one of those slips that once made is hard to spot.

Comment: Yeah, I set my $b_1$ as the integer $x$ in $12x+5y=1$, but for the rest of the problem I defined $m_1=3, $and $m_3=5$.  So my original $b_1$ should have been $b_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more direct way of solving this runs as follows. You are looking at
$$x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 3$$
$$x \equiv 2 \text{ mod } 4$$
$$x \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 5.$$
Now put $x=1+3k$ and mod this by $4$. Then $2\equiv 1 +3k \text{ mod } 4$, so $k\equiv -1 \text{ mod } 4$, say $k=4l-1$, hence $x=-2+12l$. Now take the third equation into account. Then $3 = -2+12l\text{ mod } 5$, which is equivalent to $l \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 5$, say $l=5m$. So, finally $x=-2+60m$, whence $x\equiv -2\equiv58 \text{ mod } 60$.