# Using the Chinese Remainder theorem to solve the systems of congruence's.

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

We got introduced to the Chinese Reminder Theorem, but I still haven't quite grasped it and I have a problem that asks:

> Find $x \bmod 77$ if $x \equiv 2 \pmod 7$ and $x \equiv 4 \pmod {11}$.

My attempt was like so: 
$$B = 7 * 77 * 11 = 5929$$
$$B_{1} = \frac{5929}{77} = 77$$
Using $B_{1}*x_{1} \equiv 1 \pmod {77}$: 
$$77x_{1} \equiv 1 \pmod {77} $$
$$x_{1} \equiv 78 \pmod {77}$$
So then would the $x$ be $78$?

Comment: you can look at congruences as linear algebra if you know that.

Comment: I think it needs to be done with CRT only.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation  many ways exists.

Comment: I added a remark to the answer you accepted that shows how to simplify that type of solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x\equiv 2\pmod 7$ then $x = 2+7k_1$ for some $k_1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. So substituting in your second equation you get $2+7k_1\equiv 4 \pmod {11}$, which gives you $k_1 \equiv 5\pmod{11}$, because $7^{-1}\equiv8\pmod{11}$. Hence $k_1 = 5+11k_2 $, for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$, and therefore $$x = 2+7(5+11k_2)=37+77k_2\equiv37\pmod{77} $$

Comment: Generally it ends up being simpler ordering so we do the smaller moduli *last* (vs, first as above), e.g. here $\!\bmod 7\!:\,\ 2 \equiv x \equiv 4\!+\!11\color{#c00}j \equiv 4\!-\!3j \!\iff\! 3j\equiv 2\equiv 9\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{j=3}\,$ so $\,x\equiv 4\!+\!11(\color{#c00}3)\equiv 37\pmod{\!77}\ $ Because the final modulus is smaller ($7$ vs. $11$), the final equation (and inversion) in easier to solve, viz.  $3j\equiv2\pmod{\!7}$ vs. $7k\equiv 2\pmod{\!11}.\,$ The difference in work can be much more dramatic for moduli whose size differs more greatly.

Answer (score 4):

$\bmod 7\,\&\,11\!:\ 2x\equiv -3\iff  \bmod 77\!:\ 2x\equiv -3\equiv 74\iff x\equiv 37$

Comment: We used [CCRT = Constant-case CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/860148/242), and $\,77\mid 2n\iff 77\mid n\ \ $

Comment: Shrewd! $(+1) $

Answer (score 2):

Let us use the Euclidean algorithm to express $\gcd(7,11)$ as a linear combination:
$$4 = 11 - 7\\
3 = 7 - 4 = 2 \cdot 7 - 11 \\
1 = 4 - 3 = 2 \cdot 11 - 3 \cdot 7.$$
Now, $x = (2 \cdot 11 - 3 \cdot 7) x = 2 (11x) - 3 (7x)$.  By the given congruences, $11x \equiv 11 \cdot 2 = 22 \pmod{77}$ and $7x \equiv 7 \cdot 4 = 28 \pmod{77}$.  Therefore, $x \equiv 2 \cdot 22 - 3 \cdot 28 = -40 \equiv 37 \pmod{77}$.

(This is hopefully closer to what you were hinting at in your comments as the method of solving CRT problems that your source is using.)

Comment: I didn't see them use the Euclidean algorithm, however, is there only one solution or can there be multiple(possibilities)?

Comment: Part of the statement of the Chinese Remainder Theorem is: for $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ pairwise relatively prime, $x \equiv a_1 \pmod{n_1}, \ldots, x \equiv a_k \pmod{n_k}$ has a *unique* solution modulo $n_1 \cdots n_k$.  (Though as commented elsewhere, there are certainly many different computational paths to *find* that unique solution.)

Answer (score 2):

You have to start from a *Bézout's relation* between $7$ and $11$:
$$2\cdot 11-3\cdot7=1.$$
Then the solutions to a system of congruences $\;\begin{cases}x\equiv a\pmod 7\\x\equiv b\pmod{11}\end{cases}$ is
$$x\equiv a\cdot 2\cdot 11-b\cdot 3\cdot 7\pmod{7\cdot 11}$$
Here you obtain
$x\equiv 44-84=-40\pmod{77}$. The smallest positive integer staisfying this congruence is $-40+77=37$.

The present case is trivial, but  the general method to find a Bézout's relation between two numbers is the *extended Euclidean algorithm*.

Comment: Why do you claim "you have to start from Bezout relation"? There are many ways to solve CRT systems that do not start by Bezout.

Comment: There's an ellipsis in my wording: ‘In the way I'm going to explain, you have …’

Comment: Ok, that's better. Note that it's simpler to first $\rm\color{#c00}{double}$ the congruences, because it's simpler to write $\,\color{#c00}2(b\!-\!a) = \color{#0a0}4$ (vs. $b\!-\!a=2)$ in the form $\,11j\!+\!7k\,$ (viz. $11\!-\!7=\color{#0a0}4\,$ is obvious). Equivalently, both congruences are equivalent to $\,\color{#c00}2x\equiv -3\,$ when $\,\rm\color{#c00}{doubled},\,$ as in my answer. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you have on your mind, but I would do it like this:

$x=7a+2$ and $x= 11b+4$ for some integers $a,b$ so $7a= 11b+2$ and thus $7|11b+2$.
Multiply this with 2 and we get $7|22b+4$ so $7|b-3$. Now we can write $b=7t+3$ and thus $x=77t+37$. So $x \equiv 37 \pmod {77}$.

Comment: I was going back YouTube tutorial and the person used that formula to find x, but that exactly wasn't  the CRT. He was finding the x for the CRT: Z = B1*X1*C1....So that had me lost.

Comment: @KonoDDa It's easier if we multiply by $2$ right at the start, i.e.double the congruences. Then they both unify to $\,2x\equiv -3$ and the rest is trivial - see my answer (and my comment on Bernard's answer).