# Why is (-3/77) mod 65 equal to 16?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

[Getting an X for Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20223/getting-an-x-for-chinese-remainder-theorem-crt)

In the "Easy CRT" part of the answer to this problem, the author demonstrates that (-3/77) mod 65 is equal to 16. I don't understand - how is this accurate? I sort of understand the steps, but wouldn't the answer just be 62/77?

Thanks, and I apologize if I've missed something obvious!

Comment: 62/77 is not an integer so it isn't useful

Comment: No, but useful or not, wouldn't it still be the right answer?

Comment: Well it would be an answer but $16$ would definitely be the right answer since your answer is just a reformulation of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of $\frac{1}{x}$ is that $\frac{1}{x}$ is the quantity such that $x \cdot \frac1x = 1$ (which may or may not exist). Therefore
$$ \frac{-3}{77} \equiv 16 \pmod {65} \text{ if and only if } -3 \equiv 77 \cdot 16 \pmod {65} $$
This happens if and only if
$$77 \cdot 16 + 3\equiv 0 \pmod {65}$$
which by definition of congruence mod $65$ says that
$$65 \mid (77 \cdot 16 + 3)$$
which is true because $$ 77 \cdot 16 + 3 = 1235 = 65 \cdot 19. $$

Answer (score 1):

In the ring of integers mod. $n$, there is no ‘real’ fraction. Some elements have reciprocals, others  don't, depending whether they're coprime with the modulus or not.

For instance, modulo $14$, $5$  is a unit, since $3\cdot 5\equiv 1\pmod{14}$, and $5^{-1}=3$, so one can be tempted to write, say, $\dfrac 45$ instead of $4\cdot 5^{-1}=4\cdot 3=12\pmod{14}$. This way of writing is very confusional, from my point of view.

In the present case, we have $77\equiv 12\pmod{65}$ and one computes with the *extended Euclidean algorithm* that $12^{-1}\equiv -27$, so that
$$-\frac 3{77}=(-3)(-27)=81\equiv 16\pmod{65}.$$

Comment: I'm curious about what a "real fraction" is.

Comment: I just meant  a fraction from the naive point of view.