# Solving Linear Congruence Equations

Tags: number-theory, congruences

> Solve the following congruence problem:
>
> $$N\equiv0 (\text{mod }11)$$ $$N\equiv0 (\text{mod }5)$$ $$N\equiv4
>  (\text{mod }9)$$ $$N\equiv6 (\text{mod }8)$$ $$N\equiv0 (\text{mod
>  }7)$$

I first noted that

$$\begin{align*}
N\equiv0 (\text{mod }11\cdot5\cdot7)
&\equiv0 (\text{mod }385)\\
\end{align*}$$

I now have $3$ equations:

$$N\equiv4 (\text{mod }9)$$

$$N\equiv6 (\text{mod }8)$$

$$N\equiv0 (\text{mod }385)$$

I then wrote

$$\begin{align}
N=(9\cdot8\cdot{a})+(9\cdot385\cdot{b})+(8\cdot385\cdot{c})
&=(72\cdot{a})+(3465\cdot{b})+(3080\cdot{c})
\end{align}$$

So then

$$4\equiv 3080c \equiv 2c(\text{mod }9) \Rightarrow c=2$$

$$6\equiv 3465b \equiv b(\text{mod }8) \Rightarrow b=6$$

$$0\equiv 72a \equiv 72a(\text{mod }385) \Rightarrow a=0$$

Then

$$N=(72\cdot0) + (3465\cdot6) + (3080\cdot2)=26950$$

Plugging $N$ back into the equation works out but are there more solutions? Infinitely many? If there is a more efficient way to solve this, I would be interested as well.

Comment: Solve $11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7/m \cdot a_m\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, for $m=11,5,9,8,7$, where the division just means cancelling that factor. Then $N\equiv 11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot a_{11}\cdot 0/11+11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot a_5\cdot 0/5+11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot a_9\cdot 4/9+11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot a_8\cdot 6/8+11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot a_7\cdot 0/7\pmod{11\cdot 5\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7}$ are all the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would  first group together  the congruences $N\equiv 0 \pmod{5,7,11}\iff N\equiv 0\pmod{5\cdot 7\cdot 11=385}$

Second, I'd solve the system $\;\begin{cases}N\equiv 4\pmod 9, \\ N\equiv 6\pmod 8.\end{cases}$

The effective version of the *Chinese remainder theorem* yields the solution to a system of congruences  $\;\begin{cases}N\equiv \alpha\pmod a, \\ N\equiv \beta\pmod b,\end{cases}\;$ when the moduli are coprime and we have a *Bézout's relation*: $\;ua+vb=1$. This solution is
$$N\equiv \beta ua+\alpha vb \pmod{ab}. $$

Now, as $9-8=1$, the solutions to the second group of congruences is 
$$N\equiv6\cdot9-4\cdot8=22\pmod{72}.$$

Last, we have to find a Bézout's relation between $385$ and $72$ to solve the system of congruences $\;\begin{cases}N\equiv 0\pmod{385},\\ N\equiv 22\pmod{72}.\end{cases}$

This is done with the *extended Euclidean algorithm*:
$$\begin{array}{rrrr}
r_i&u_i&v_i&q_i \\
\hline
385&1&0\\
72&0&1&5 \\
\hline
25&1&-5&2 \\
22&-2&11&1 \\
3&3&-16&7 \\
\color{red}{1}&\color{red}{-23}& \color{red}{123} \\\hline
\end{array}$$
Thus a Bézout's relation is $\; -23\cdot 385+123\cdot75=1$, and the solution of the system of congruences is
$$N\equiv-22\cdot23\cdot 385+0\cdot123\cdot 72=-194810\equiv \color{red}{-770}\pmod{72\cdot 385= \color{red}{27720}}.$$

Comment: Thank you, this explanation helped a lot!

Comment: **Or** $\bmod 70\!:\ (9N\equiv 54) - (8N\equiv 32)\Rightarrow N\equiv 22,\,$ a special case of the fractional extended Euclidean algorithm at the end of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242)

Answer (score 2):

I would solve each equation, and modify the solution as I go.

After the fist two equations.

$N = 55k$

Plugging that into the 3rd.

$55k \equiv k\pmod 9\\
k = 4$

$N = 4\cdot 55 + 55\cdot 9\cdot k = 220+495 k$

And continue this way through the last 2 equations.

$220+495k \equiv 4 -k\pmod 8$

$k\equiv -2 \equiv 6\pmod 8$

$N = 3190 + 3960k \equiv 5 + 5k \pmod 7\\
k = 6\\
N = 26,950 + 27,720k$

Comment: @Remy Indeed I did.  Transcription error.

Comment: How did you arrive at $N=4\cdot 55 + 55 \cdot 9 \cdot{k}$?

Comment: $55k \equiv k \pmod9, 55\cdot 4 \equiv 4\pmod {9}$ and $55\cdot 9 k \equiv 0\pmod 9$

Answer (score 1):

By [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) there are infinitely many solutions with $$N=26950 \pmod{11\cdot 5\cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}$$