# A question about modulo with high number

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The question I got is

$$
42^{27} \bmod  55
$$
And the answer I got is like this

$$
42(42^{2})^{13} \bmod  55
\\42(1764)^{13} \bmod  55
\\42(4)^{13} \bmod  55
\\42(67108864) \bmod  55
\\42(9) \bmod 55
\\378 \bmod 55
\\ 48 \bmod 55
$$

So on the third/fifth step, why $1764$ turn into $4$ and why $67108864$ turns into $9$?

I have already read others similar question but still don't get the idea about what is happening

Comment: Do you know what $\rm mod$ stands for, to begin with?

Comment: I do but I just don't know how to deal with a big number

Comment: They used $\ 1764\equiv 4\pmod{55}\ $ and the [Congruence Product & Power Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Ditto for $\, 4^{13}\equiv 9\ \ \ $

Comment: OK....I think I understand now.....thanks both of you :D

Comment: Same way you'd deal with a smaller number. Also, 1764 is not all that big.

Comment: nah I mean 42^27 is big lol and my calculator cannot handle that...and I used to do these questions with my calculator and not by hand

Comment: $$42^{27}=67255970008406099921710928456387385568002048$$It is really not that big.

Comment: but...I mean the thing is....my Casio fx-50FH cannot output that number....so

Comment: OK, but you don't really need to handle $42^{27}$ directly. You know how to avoid that, and 1764 or even 67108864 must be well within manageable limits for the calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used $\ 1764\equiv 4\pmod{55}\ $ and the [Congruence Product & Power Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). Ditto for $\, 4^{\large 13}\!\equiv 9.\ $

Generally congruence is *preserved* by replacing aguments of sums and products by any congruent argument, e.g. see the Polynomial Congruence Rule in the above linked answer.

> I just don't know how to deal with a big number

CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem helps by reducing to smaller moduli. Applying CRT here along with [modular order reduction of exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) we obtain by easy mental arithmetic

$\!\bmod 5\!:\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2^{\large 4} \equiv 1\, \Rightarrow\ 42^{\large 27}\ \ \equiv\ \ \  2^{\large\color{#c00}{27}}\  \ \,\equiv\,\ \  2^{\large\color{#c00} 3}\ \equiv\ \color{#0a0}3,\ \ $ by $\ \ \color{#c00}{27\equiv 3}\pmod{4}$

$\!\bmod 11\!:\,\ (-2)^{\large 5} \equiv 1\, \Rightarrow\, 42^{\large 27 }\equiv (-2)^{\large{27}} \equiv (-2)^{\large 2} \equiv \color{#90f}4,\, \ \ $ by $\ \ 27\equiv 2\pmod{5}$

Thus applying [easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242):  $ \ \ \ 42^{\large 27} \equiv  \color{#90f}4 + 11\left[\dfrac{\color{#0a0}3-\color{#90f}4}{11} \bmod 5\right]\equiv 4+11[-1]\equiv -7\equiv 48\pmod{\!55}$

By reducing the moduli to $5$ & $11$ we can now do the arithmetic in a couple minutes  *purely mentally*.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html,

$\lambda(55)=20$

As $(42,55)=1,27\equiv7\pmod{20}$

$42^{27}\equiv42^7\pmod{55}$

Now  $42^2\equiv4\pmod{55}$

$\implies42^7=42(42^2)^3\equiv(-13)(2^2)^3\pmod{55}$

$\equiv(-13)9\equiv-117\equiv-117+3\cdot55$

Comment: I think you meant $42^\color{red}7=42(42^2)^3$

Comment: @Tanner, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 0):

In the ring $\mathbb Z/55\mathbb Z$ we have

$42^{27}=(-13)^{27}=-13^{27}$

$13^2=169=4\Rightarrow13^{27}=4^{13}\cdot13=9\cdot13=7$.

Thus $$42^{27}=-7=48$$

Comment: But how did ypu compute $\,4^{\large 13}\equiv 9\,?\,$ That omitted step is where most of the work lies above so one should say something about that (esp. given the OP's comment "I just don't know how to deal with a big number")  $\ \ $

Comment: If the guy can not apply successive reductions when relevant, then he can not assimilate to the total understanding theorems like the Chinese theorem or similar ones, generally "complicated" for beginners.  My last two answers have not appeared on the corresponding list, Why?

Comment: That doesn't answer my query, i.e. how did *you* compute it?  We don't know what the OP (and readers) know, but the more fully we explain the greater the possibility it will be helpful.

Comment: It is not important but anyway you have $4^3=9$; $9^4=16$ and $16\cdot4=9$. Regards.

Comment: So it appears that you are essentially using [powering by repeated squaring.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). The OP may not be aware of that method so it is always helpful to be explicit.