# I am asked to solve the following system of congruences: 2z≡ 6 mod 36, 3z ≡ 7 mod 8.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I see $\gcd(2,36)=2$ and divides $6$ so I divide and receive $z\equiv3 \pmod {18}$.

For $3z\equiv7\pmod 8$ I see $\gcd(3,8)=1$ and 1 divides 7. I also see that to reduce $3z\equiv7\pmod8$, I multiply by 3 which gives me $21\pmod8$. I am then left with $z\equiv3\pmod{18}$ and $z\equiv21\pmod 8$.

I then proceeded to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem on these two congruences and receive my answer.

My CRT work: 18 x 8=144
a=3 b=21
8(mod 18) = 8
18(mod 8) = 2,
3 x 8 x 8 = 192,
21 x 18 x 2 = 756,
192+756 = 948,
948(mod 144) = 84(mod 144)

However, I was told this was wrong but I am unsure why, if anyone can help point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: Who asked you to solve the system of congruences?  Name of class?  Name of text book?  Very passive voice: "I am asked", "I was told":  Who asked you, and who told you..?

Comment: always split into prime powers  for problems done by hand. You have $2z \equiv 6 \pmod 9,  $ then  $2z \equiv 6 \pmod 4,  $   as well as $3z \equiv 7 \pmod 8.  $  Then you need to check that the examples with powers of $2$  are consistent. In the end you have someting mod 9 and something mod 8, together something mod 72

Comment: Dana Please show your work following" "I then proceeded to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, ... and receive my answer."  Please show us your work and your answer.

Comment: Hello, I added my CRT work but do not know how to format it properly

Comment: Dana, I recommend against attempting to use CRT  with moduli that share a gcd. Try the bit with moduli 4,8   and 9, combine the 4,8 into a single mod 8,  then combine moduli 8,9 into mod 72

Comment: Hi, I was unaware that you can combine 2 moduli into a single mod as you suggest combining the 4,8 into a single 8. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Dana, I wrote them above;  recommend you solve $2z \equiv 6 \pmod 4$  and $3z \equiv 7 \pmod 8$   by simply trying $z$ values from $0$ to $7;$   or $1$ to $8$ if you prefer.   Note detail: $2z \equiv 6 \pmod 4$  means the same thing as $2z \equiv 2 \pmod 4$

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your help! With your advice, I received z=5. I then have the congruences: z≡5(mod 8) and z≡3(mod 9). Using CRT I eventually got the answer 21(mod 72). Is this correct?

Comment: Dana  yes, that is correct

Comment: And this follows from the LCM generalization of CRT. The coprime case has LCM equal to product.

Comment: By [General Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) in the linked dupe:
$$\begin{align} \begin{array}{}&x\equiv 3\pmod{\!18}\\&x\equiv 5\pmod{\!8}\end{array}\!\!&\iff x\equiv 3+18\left[\dfrac{(5\!-\!3)/2}{\ \ \ \ \ \ 18/2}\bmod 8/2 \right]\!\!\!\pmod{\!18(8)/2}\\[.4em]
&\iff x\equiv 3+18\,[\,2/1\,\bmod\, 4\,]\,\equiv\, 21\pmod{72}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$2z\equiv 6\bmod 36\Rightarrow 2z=36t+6\Rightarrow z=18t+3\rightarrow 3z=54 t+9$

$3z\equiv 7\bmod 8 \Rightarrow 3z=8t_1+7$

So we have to solve following equation:

$54t+9=8t_1+7, Or:, -27t+4t_1=1$

One solution to this equation is $(t, t_1)=(1, 7)$ so we have:

$t=4s+1$ and $t_1=27 s+7$ such that:

$3z=54(4s+1)+9=8(27 s+7)+7=216 s+63$

Or:

$z=72 s+21\rightarrow z\equiv 21\bmod 72$.

Comment: Typo on the first line, should be $2z\equiv 6\pmod {36}\implies 3z\equiv 9\pmod {53}$

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin{cases}2z\equiv6\pmod{36}\\3z\equiv7\pmod8\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}2z=6+36X\\3z=7+8Y\end{cases}\Rightarrow8Y-54X=2\iff4Y-27X=1$$
The general solution of this last equation is get standard way by the help of a single solution, in this case$(X,Y)=(7,1)$ so $X=4n+1$ (not necessary to get $Y$)so
$$z=3+18X=72n+21\text{ where } n\in\mathbb Z$$