# Easier way to compute the solution to a modular equation system

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Using the extended euclidian algorithm and the Chinese remainder theorem, I am able to find a solution to the following equation system:

\begin{align*}
x \equiv 4 \bmod 39\\
x \equiv 5 \bmod 70
\end{align*}

The issue I have is that while I am able to find the solution (which is $355$), many steps of the Chinese remainder theorem require multiplying large numbers together (eg: $4\cdot 31\cdot34$) and finding the result of modulo operations on other large numbers (eg: $11275 \bmod 355$).

What seems impractical about this is that this is destined to be part of a handwritten test where calculators aren't authorized.
In the previous question of the test, it was asked to compute the modular inverse of $39 \bmod 70$, which is $9$ and from what the test specifies this should help solve the system, unfortunately I don't see how to do this.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: These are operations well within the range of pen and paper working.  The product is $4216$ done mentally and checked.  You can find $11275 \bmod 355$ with two cycles of long division.  Your course expects you to be able to do this.  Be glad they are not $10$ or $20$ digits.

Comment: There are only two equations.  Starting with the bottom one, we now try to solve $5+70n\equiv 4 \pmod {39}$, which is not difficult.  It is equivalent to $8n\equiv 1 \pmod {39}$ and the inverse of $8\pmod {39}$ is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Easy CRT Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242), & by  [twiddling to an $\color{#c00}{\text{exact quotient}\equiv 5}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

$\ \begin{align}\rm x&\equiv\color{#0a0}{5\!\!\!\pmod{\!70}} \\
\rm x&\equiv \color{#90f}{4\!\!\!\pmod{\!39}}\end{align}
  \!\!\iff\! $ $ x \equiv\, \color{#0a0}{5\! +\! 70} \bigg(\!\underbrace{\dfrac{\color{#90f}4\!-\!\color{#0a0}5}{\color{#0a0}{70}}\!\color{#90f}{\bmod{39}}}_{\small{\dfrac{\color{#90f}{-}\color{#0a0}1}{\color{#0a0}{70}}\ \,\equiv\,\ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{-40}{-8}\ \equiv\ \large 5}}}\!\bigg)$ $\equiv 355\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}{70}\cdot \color{#90f}{39}}$

Comment: Took only $10$ seconds of easy mental arithmetic. We could also compute $\,1/70 \bmod 39\,$ by various other methods in the "twiddling" linked post.

Comment: Thank you! The colors are very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

let $x=39y+4$
$39y+4\equiv 5\pmod{70}$
$39y\equiv 1\pmod{70}$
the inverse of 39 mod 70 is 9
$y\equiv 9\pmod{70}$
$y=70z+9$
$x=39(70z+9)+4=39*70z+355$
$x\equiv 355\pmod{39*70}$

Comment: You omitted the computation of $\,39^{-1}\bmod 70,\,$ which might be more work than everything above if it's done w/o optimization. For one easy way see my 2nd comment on lulu's answer.

Comment: Thank   you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done entirely in your head.

From the second congruence, we know that $x=5+70n$ for some $n$.  Thus we seek to solve $$5+70n\equiv 4\pmod {39}$$

But this is equivalent to $$8n\equiv 1 \pmod {39}\implies n\equiv 5\pmod {39}$$ and we are done.

Comment: this method seems easier because the inverse of 8 mod 39 is easier to compute than the inverse of 39 mod 70.

Comment: @cineel.  Indeed, it's always better to work with smaller moduli.  Were it necessary, you could go further and work modulo $3,13$ separately, but this is not necessary.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, the method used above a special case of a general CRT formula.  It's not clear what method was used to compute $1/8\bmod 39$ but thar too can be viewed as a special case of various general methods of computing modular fractions - see my "twiddling" link.

Comment: @cineel Usually inverting wrt least modulus is easier, but here $\,39^{-1}\equiv 9\pmod{\!70}\,$ is easy too

$\!\bmod 35\!:\ \dfrac{1}{39}\equiv \dfrac{36}4_{\phantom{|_|}}\!\!\!\equiv 9.\,$ It's also true  $\!\bmod 2\!:\ \overbrace{39^{-1}\equiv 9}^{\textstyle\ 1^{-1}\equiv 1}\,$ so it's also true $\!\bmod 2\cdot 35\,$ (by $\,2,35\mid 9\cdot 39-1\Rightarrow \,2\cdot 35\mid 9\cdot 39-1).\,$ Above we  *twiddled* the fraction to get an exact quotient $36/4$ (cf. link in my answer)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was very helpful.