# Given two divisors of a number and its remainders, calculate what that number is

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In the courtyard of a school, more than 100 children were playing and less than 200. If they were grouped in groups of 7, there would be 2 children left. If they were put together in groups of 11, there would be 3 children left. How many children were there in the courtyard?(Answer:$135$)

I try

$n=7q+2$

$n=11q_1+3∴7q+2=11q_1+3⟹7q−11q_1=1$

Is there a relationship between the quotientes?

Comment: @user2661923  "n"  is the total number of children in the garden.

Comment: If you have never worked with problems like this before, and if you have received no Number Theory training, then I advise brute force.  From the constraints, $(n-2) \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$ and $(n-2) \equiv 1 \pmod{11}.$  Why not manually check which element $r$ in $\{0,1,2,\cdots,10\}$ is such that $7r \equiv 1\pmod{11}.$  Then, you will be guaranteed that $(n-2)$ must have form $7 \times (r + 11k)$, where $k$ is some integer.

Comment: @user2661923 It's the basics of division. The dividend(n) is equal to the quotient(q,q1) times the divisor(7,11)plus the remainder(2,3).

Comment: I understand that.  The point of my now deleted comments was for you to proofread and edit your posting, which you have done.

Comment: Use CRT to solve $\,n\equiv 2\pmod{7},\ n\equiv 3\pmod{11},\,$ e.g. via [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your number to be $k$ where $k∈(100,200)$,

As you said,

$$k=7n_1+2=11n_2+3$$ Where $n_1,n_2∈\mathbb{N}$

So, by above equation$$ 7n_1-11n_2=1$$

As there is constraint for $k$, $n_2∈[9,17]$, on checking we get $n_2=12$, as $n_1$ is also an integer.

So, $k=135, n_1=19, n_2=12$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Spreading knowledge matters bro!

Comment: Wouldn't that be  $ in_2 \in$ [9.17] $ ?  because  $ 11.18+3=201 > 200 $ and $ 9.11+3 =102 > 100$

Comment: Oh yes! But that wasn't of no use. But I'll correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Let number of students is n; the number theory equalaent to youquestion is:

Remainder of number n when divided by 7 is 2 and when it is divided by 11 the remainder is 3, find n.

We can write:

$n=7t+2=11t_1+3\Rightarrow -7 t+11 t_1=-1\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$

one solution to this equation is $(t, t_1)=(8, 5)$

The homogeneous equation of (1) is:

$11 t_1-7 t=0$

and it's solution is: $t_1=7$ and $t=11$ and we  can write the general form of solutions as:

$t=11\alpha+8$ and $t_1=7\beta +5$

So we have (1) in form of:

$n=7(11\alpha+8)+2=11(7\beta +5)+3$

Or:

$77\alpha+58=77\beta+58$

For $\alpha=\beta=1$ equation gives $n=135$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).