# A number when divided by 2,3,4,5,6 leaves remainder 1,2,3,4,5 respectively but when its divided by 11 the remainder is 0. FIND THE NUMBER

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, chinese-remainder-theorem

A number when divided by $2,3,4,5,6$ leaves remainder $1,2,3,4,5$ respectively but when its divided by $11$ the remainder is $0$. FIND THE NUMBER

I tried taking **LCM** of $2,3,4,5,6$ and subratcing by $1(59)$ then multiply by $11$. What am i doing wrong? Please Guide.

Comment: Hint:  Remainder is $~-1~$ when divided by each of $~2,3,4,5,6.~$  So, $~60k - 1 = 11a.~$  An inelegant approach to completing the problem is that since $~60 \equiv 5 \pmod{11},~$ you have that $~5k -1~$ must be a multiple of $~11.$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You need to solve $x\equiv-1\bmod60$ and $x\equiv0\bmod11$.  Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?  An indication of what you are doing wrong is that the remainder when $x$ is divided by $3$ is not the same as the remainder when $11x$ is divided by $3$

Comment: Beginning with $\,11,\,$ and given divisors $\,(2,3,4,5,6),\,$ the pattern of remainders $(1,2,3,x,5)$ is found every $\,12^{th}\,$ multiple of $\,11.\quad$  Finally, at $\,N=11\cdot49=539,\,$  the pattern becomes  $(1,2,3,4,5).\quad$

Comment: In your text, is this problem before or after the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem ?  So: is this problem preliminary motivation for the CRT, or are you supposed to solve this using the CRT?

Comment: As a complete beginner to number theory and these types of questions, here is my attempt:

2m - 11n = 1

gcd(2, -11) = gcd(2, 11) = 1
-11 = 2 * -5 - 1
==> 1 = 2(-5) + 11

m = -5, n = -1

x = 11n = -11

Of course there are an infinite number of solutions but I'm too lazy to find the general formula

Comment: By CCRT (in first dupe) we know the first $5$ congruences are equivalent to $\,x\equiv -1\pmod{60}.\,$ Further, by the [Easy CRT formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) we have $$\begin{align} x&\equiv -1\pmod{60}\\ x&\equiv\ \,0\ \pmod{11}\end{align}\iff \bmod 660\!:\ x\equiv 11(\color{#c00}{-11^{-1}}\bmod 60)\equiv 11(\color{#c00}{-11})\equiv 539$$ Your error is applying an incorrect CRT method to solve the prior congruence system, viz. $\bmod 60\!:\ x = 11\color{#c00}n\equiv -1\iff \color{#c00}{n\equiv -11^{-1}}\ \ $

Comment: thank you everyone figured out what i was doing wrong!!

Answer (score 2):

Let $n$ be that number then $n+1$ can divisible by $2,3,4,5,6$ without remainder.

$\newcommand{\lcm}{\operatorname{lcm}}\lcm(2,3,4,5,6)=60$

$n+1=60k, k\in Z$

and if the number is divisible by $11$

$n=11t,t\in Z$

by solving

$$n+1=60k, k\in Z$$
$$n=11t,t\in Z$$

$n=60k-1=11t$, $ k , t\in Z$

$t=5k+\frac{5k-1}{11}$

for $k=9, t=49$

then

$$n=539$$

In general
$$n\equiv 539  \mod  {660}$$

Comment: The general expression for $n$ is $n=660m-121$, where $m$ can be any integer.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).