# Chinese Remainder Theorem without GDC=1

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I was looking at this problem: The smallest positive integer greater than 1 that leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by 4, 5, and 6 lies between which of the following pairs of numbers?
I was wondering if you could solve this using Chinese Remainder Theorem, I am new to using Chinese Remainder Theorem but I'm fairly certain you need the GDC for all mods equal to 1 and clearly GDC(4,6)=2, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Call the answer $n$. From $n\equiv 1\pmod 6$, this breaks into both $n\equiv 1\pmod 2$ and $\pmod 3$.

Comment: Notice that if $x \equiv 1 \pmod {nm}$ then $nm|x-1$ so $n|x-1$ and $m|x-1$ so $x\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod m$.  So, .... sure, $4$ and $6$ are not relatively prime but $4$ and $3$ are and as $x\equiv 1 \pmod 6$ you have $x\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  So you have $x\equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod 3$.  Chinese Remainder away till you are blue in the face.

Comment: @peterwhy, I don't really understand how?

Comment: Applying CCRT twice: $\ x\equiv a\pmod {\!m\ \&\ n\ \&\ k}\iff x\equiv a\pmod{\!\ell},\,\ \ell = {\rm lcm}(m,n,k)$

Comment: Generally for noncoprime moduli a slight tweak of the CRT formula works, see [general Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242). In particular this method uses only fast gcds  (not slow prime factorizations), which is crucial when the numbers are large.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is $1$ more than a multiple of $4$, and of $5$, and of $6$, then it is $1$ more than a multiple of their least common multiple (LCM).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)